# How can I convert a long to int in Java?

Tags: java

How can I convert a long to int in Java?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safely casting long to int in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590831/safely-casting-long-to-int-in-java)

Comment: ``if ((lval <= Integer.MAX_VALUE) && (lval >= Integer.MIN_VALUE)) intValue = (int)lval;``

Answer (score 515):

**Updated, in Java 8:**

```
Math.toIntExact(value);
```

**Original Answer:**

Simple type casting should do it:

```
long l = 100000;
int i = (int) l;
```

Note, however, that large numbers (usually larger than `2147483647` and smaller than `-2147483648`) will lose some of the bits and would be represented incorrectly.

For instance, `2147483648` would be represented as `-2147483648`.

Comment: What is the precision of integers? o_O

Comment: Casting has different meanings for objects and for primitive types.  (int) l doesn't try to treat a 64-bit integer as a 32-bit integer, it actually returns a different 32-bit integer with the same 32 lower order bits.  With objects, you cast to a more specific child class, but with primitve types, a cast is not really a cast, but a conversion.

Comment: Int x = (int)(((Long)Integer.MAX_INTEGER)+10);
If a conversion doesn't detect in this case that x has an improper value then you don't have a solution.

Comment: Math.toIntExact() is a great method actually.  It throws and exception if the value is too big to fit in an int.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 215):

```
Long x = 100L;
int y = x.intValue();
```

Comment: Note the types. Its not a primitive `long` here. Its the reference type `Long` which cant directly cast to an primitive `int`. `int y = (int)x;` will throws an execption but `int y = (int)(long)x` will work. (The reason is autoboxing)

Answer (score 73):

For small values, casting is enough:

```
long l = 42;
int i = (int) l;
```

However, a `long` can hold more information than an `int`, so it's not possible to perfectly convert from `long` to `int`, in the general case. If the `long` holds a number less than or equal to `Integer.MAX_VALUE` you can convert it by casting without losing any information.

For example, the following sample code:

```
System.out.println( "largest long is " + Long.MAX_VALUE );
System.out.println( "largest int is " + Integer.MAX_VALUE );

long x = (long)Integer.MAX_VALUE;
x++;
System.out.println("long x=" + x);

int y = (int) x;
System.out.println("int y=" + y);
```

produces the following output on my machine:

```
largest long is 9223372036854775807
largest int is 2147483647
long x=2147483648
int y=-2147483648
```

Notice the negative sign on `y`. Because `x` held a value one larger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, `int y` was unable to hold it.  In this case, it wrapped around to the negative numbers.

If you wanted to handle this case yourself, you might do something like:

```
if ( x > (long)Integer.MAX_VALUE ) {
    // x is too big to convert, throw an exception or something useful
}
else {
    y = (int)x;
}
```

All of this assumes positive numbers. For negative numbers, use `MIN_VALUE` instead of `MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: So a proper conversion will be to detect if the conversion is safe and throw an exception otherwise. Fact stated by @Andrej Herich that suggested Guava library.

Comment: Starting from Java 8, you could  simly use Math.toIntExact

Answer (score 68):

Since Java 8
you can use: Math.toIntExact(long value)

[See JavaDoc: Math.toIntExact](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toIntExact-long-)

> Returns the value of the long argument; throwing an exception if the value overflows an int.

Source code of `Math.toIntExact` in JDK 8:

```
public static int toIntExact(long value) {
    if ((int)value != value) {
        throw new ArithmeticException("integer overflow");
    }
    return (int)value;
}
```

Answer (score 39):

If using [Guava library](https://github.com/google/guava), there are methods [`Ints.checkedCast(long)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#checkedCast(long)) and [`Ints.saturatedCast(long)`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#saturatedCast(long)) for converting `long` to `int`.

Comment: There is no need of using libraries

Comment: @Grekz that's up to the OP. I would in this case. More dependency jars is better than more reinvented wheels unless you have an actual reason not to have more dependency jars.

Comment: IMHO, this answer is much better than the accepted one, in that it never does something unexpected.

Comment: Since my project already include that jar, it would be more benefit to use it than to write a new helper

Answer (score 30):

```
long x = 3;
int y = (int) x;
```

but that assumes that the `long` can be represented as an `int`, you do know the difference between the two?

Comment: Interesting to know is that according to par 5.1.3 in http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#189955 (The Java Language Spec): Despite the fact that overflow, underflow, or other loss of information may occur, narrowing conversions among primitive types never result in a run-time exception (§11).

Answer (score 28):

You can use the `Long` wrapper instead of `long` primitive and call

```
Long.intValue()
```

[Java7 intValue() docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#intValue())

It rounds/truncate the `long` value accordingly to fit in an `int`.

Comment: It may be a good idea to link to the current documentation, as well as expand on this - inevitably, there's going to be some degree of rounding when converting a long to an int.

Comment: Looking at the Java 7 implementation of Long.intValue(), it's just casting. No under/overflow checking is implemented.  So at least through Java 7, this option is equivalent to just: (int)someLong.

Comment: why less upvotes ? I found this one of most valuable Answer

Answer (score 12):

Shortest, most safe and easiest solution is:

```
long myValue=...;
int asInt = Long.valueOf(myValue).intValue();
```

Do note, the behavior of `Long.valueOf` is as such:

Using this code:

```
System.out.println("Long max: " + Long.MAX_VALUE);
System.out.println("Int max: " + Integer.MAX_VALUE);        
long maxIntValue = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
System.out.println("Long maxIntValue to int: " + Long.valueOf(maxIntValue).intValue());
long maxIntValuePlusOne = Integer.MAX_VALUE + 1;
System.out.println("Long maxIntValuePlusOne to int: " + Long.valueOf(maxIntValuePlusOne).intValue());
System.out.println("Long max to int: " + Long.valueOf(Long.MAX_VALUE).intValue());
```

Results into:

```
Long max: 9223372036854775807
Int max: 2147483647
Long max to int: -1
Long maxIntValue to int: 2147483647
Long maxIntValuePlusOne to int: -2147483648
```

Answer (score 6):

If direct casting shows error you can do it like this:

```
Long id = 100;
int int_id = (int) (id % 100000);
```

Answer (score 4):

In Java, a long is a signed 64 bits number, which means you can store numbers between -9,223,372,036,854,775,808 and 9,223,372,036,854,775,807 (inclusive).

An int, on the other hand, is signed 32 bits number, which means you can store numbers between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647 (inclusive).

So if your long is outside of the values permitted for an int, you will not get a valuable conversion.

Details about sizes of primitive Java types here:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Answer (score 3):

In **Java 8** I do in following way

```
long l = 100L;
int i = Math.toIntExact(l);
```

This method throws `ArithmaticException` if `long` value exceed range of `int`. Thus I am safe from data loss.

Answer (score 1):

Manual typecasting can be done here:

```
long x1 = 1234567891;
int y1 = (int) x1;
System.out.println("in value is " + y1);
```

Comment: Please do not answer with a comment/question. Understandably, your rep is too low to comment, but that still does not mean answers should be used to make comments as an alternative. It would be preferable if you deleted this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a safe conversion and enjoy the use of Java8 with Lambda expression
You can use it like:

```
val -> Optional.ofNullable(val).map(Long::intValue).orElse(null)
```

Comment: You mean declaring it like `Function<Long,Integer> function =`?

Answer (score 0):

```
long x;
int y;
y = (int) x
```

You can cast a long to int so long as the number is less than 2147483647 without an error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding few key details.

Basically what Java does is truncate `long` after 32 bits, so simple typecasting will do the trick:

```
    long l=100000000000000000l;
    System.out.println(Long.toString(l,2));
    int t=(int)l;
    System.out.println(Integer.toString(t,2));
```

Which outputs:

```
101100011010001010111100001011101100010100000000000000000
                          1011101100010100000000000000000
```

for `l=1000000043634760000l` it outputs:

```
110111100000101101101011110111010000001110011001100101000000
                             -101111110001100110011011000000
```

If we convert this `-101111110001100110011011000000` in proper two's compliment we will get the exact 32-bit signed truncated from the `long`.

Answer (score 0):

```java
// Java Program to convert long to int
  
class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  
    // create long variable
    long value1 = 523386L;
    long value2 = -4456368L;
  
    // change long to int
    int num1 = Math.toIntExact(value1);
    int num2 = Math.toIntExact(value2);
      
    // print the type
    System.out.println("Converted type: "+ ((Object)num1).getClass().getName());
    System.out.println("Converted type: "+ ((Object)num2).getClass().getName());
  
    // print the int value
    System.out.println(num1);  // 52336
    System.out.println(num2);  // -445636
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to directly narrowly typecast/cast up from the higher data type (the long) to the lower one (the int), which would look like:

```
    long x = 101010101L;

    //explicit type casting
    int y=(int)x;
```

Note that there would be some issues with a loss of data due to the smaller range of values accepted by the int.

```
    long l = 2147483648L;

    // 
    // T
    // And we are trying to store a value in i 
    // greater than its upper limit
    int i = (int) l;
```

(prints as -2147483648)

This would not be an issue with your example value. You can do this because both types of data are primitive values; whereas, if you were converting a string to an integer you would not be able to do this due to the string contents including characters, which are not accepted values for integers.

You would also be able to engage in explicit type conversion, which is used when converting the value of one data type to another data type without the compiler being able to do so. This would look like

```
    //returns argument as int
    //will throw ArithmaticException if the result overflows the int
    //aka it is out of the range of -2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647
    int b=Math.toIntExact(x);

    int c= x.IntValue();
```

Note how this throws an exception when the long is out of range to be stored as an int rather than engaging in wraparound behavior and counting up from the negative limit of int after exceeding the maximum value of int.

When choosing between type casting or type conversion, you should note that casting changes the type of the variable, while conversion changes the representation or format of the value. Casting converts between compatible data types, while conversion can convert incompatible data types as well. Casting can result in data loss or truncation with narrowing (as in your case), while conversion can involve the manipulation or changing of data without changing the data type.

You can also reference here for more information:

https://www.scaler.com/topics/java/type-casting-in-java/

Answer (score -2):

long x = 3120L;  //take any long value
int z =  x.intValue();  //you can convert double to int also in the same way

if you needto covert directly then

longvalue.intvalue();

Comment: This is wrong, 3.120 is not a long, it is a double or floating point number.

Answer (score -4):

I Also Faced This Problem.
To Solve This I have first converted my long to String then to int.

```
int i = Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(long));
```

Answer (score -5):

```
Long l = 100;
int i = Math.round(l);
```

Answer (score -8):

In Spring, there is a rigorous way to convert a long to int

not only lnog can convert into int,any type of class extends Number can convert to other Number type in general,here I will show you how to convert a long to int,other type vice versa.

```
Long l = 1234567L;
int i = org.springframework.util.NumberUtils.convertNumberToTargetClass(l, Integer.class);
```

[image: convert long to int]

Comment: Spring may be Java, but Java is not Spring. "In java, there is" is a false statement.