# How can I cast a Long to an int in Java?

Tags: java

```
Long x;
int y = (int) x;
```

Eclipse is marking this line with the error:

> Can not cast Long to an int

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert long to int?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355303/how-to-convert-long-to-int)

Comment: Nope, not a dupe. The other question is about converting a `long`, this one's about converting a `Long`. Big difference!

Comment: Note that Long and long are different. "Long" is the class that wraps a value of the primitive type "long".

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use primitive `long`

```
long x = 23L;
int  y = (int) x;
```

You can't cast an Object (Long is an Object) to a primitive, the only exception being the corresponding primitive / wrapper type through auto (un) boxing

If you must convert a `Long` to an int, use `Long.intValue()`:

```
Long x = 23L;
int  y = x.intValue();
```

But beware: you may be losing information! A `Long` / `long` has 64 bit and can hold much more data than an `Integer` / `int` (32 bit only)

Comment: Also make sure that x is not null, as a Long can be null while a long can't.

Comment: @Thomas - Depends on the context, but I can imagine that in case of a null Long, getting a NPE is fine.

Answer (score 15):

`Long x` is an object.

```
int y = x.intValue();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
int y = (int) (long) x;
```

is working.

Comment: IMHO: Double and triple casts tend to be confusing and are best avoided.

Answer (score 2):

```
Long x1 = 123L;
long x2 = 123L;


int y1 = Math.toIntExact(x1);
int y2 = Math.toIntExact(x2);
```

**This conversion will work with primitive as well as with non-primitive types as well.**