# Convert Long into Integer

Tags: java

How to convert a [`Long`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) value into an [`Integer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) value in Java?

Comment: first you need to check if you Long doesn't exceed Integer MaxValue.

Comment: Java 8: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36331461/2291056

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a long to int in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355303/how-can-i-convert-a-long-to-int-in-java)

Answer (score 605, accepted):

```
Integer i = theLong != null ? theLong.intValue() : null;
```

or if you don't need to worry about null:

```
// auto-unboxing does not go from Long to int directly, so
Integer i = (int) (long) theLong;
```

And in both situations, you might run into overflows (because a Long can store a wider range than an Integer).

Java 8 has a helper method that checks for overflow (you get an exception in that case):

```
Integer i = theLong == null ? null : Math.toIntExact(theLong);
```

Comment: It's the best answer because it handles NULL values.

Comment: @ViacheslavDobromyslov the question was about Long values, not about null values. And personally I believe in rejecting null up front rather than using null in -> null out and thereby transporting null through my application. So one could also argue this is the worst answer :-)

Comment: Why would you cast twice when you can just call `intValue` instead ? Plus it is going to unbox to long, cast to int, and rebox to `Integer`, which does not seem very useful. I don't see the point on top of my head, do you have a good reason for this ?

Comment: I am getting the error: Cannot invoke intValue() on the primitive type long

Comment: Anand it is because you initialized your value using 'long' instead of using 'Long' (primitive versus wrapper class)

Comment: why are you using `(int) (long) theLong` and not just `(int) theLong` ??

Comment: @mrid Because that does not compile: "Long cannot be converted to int"

Comment: @Thilo oh, I get it. Basically you're converting `Long` to `long` first, and then to `int`

Answer (score 133):

Here are three ways to do it:

```
Long l = 123L;
Integer correctButComplicated = Integer.valueOf(l.intValue());
Integer withBoxing = l.intValue();
Integer terrible = (int) (long) l;
```

All three versions generate almost identical byte code:

```
 0  ldc2_w <Long 123> [17]
 3  invokestatic java.lang.Long.valueOf(long) : java.lang.Long [19]
 6  astore_1 [l]
 // first
 7  aload_1 [l]
 8  invokevirtual java.lang.Long.intValue() : int [25]
11  invokestatic java.lang.Integer.valueOf(int) : java.lang.Integer [29]
14  astore_2 [correctButComplicated]
// second
15  aload_1 [l]
16  invokevirtual java.lang.Long.intValue() : int [25]
19  invokestatic java.lang.Integer.valueOf(int) : java.lang.Integer [29]
22  astore_3 [withBoxing]
// third
23  aload_1 [l]
// here's the difference:
24  invokevirtual java.lang.Long.longValue() : long [34]
27  l2i
28  invokestatic java.lang.Integer.valueOf(int) : java.lang.Integer [29]
31  astore 4 [terrible]
```

Comment: Minor styliustic issue: You should probably use the upper-case suffix `123L` for readability.

Comment: Or you can use a good font... and here we go again... :D (just j/k, I also do that)

Comment: @ViacheslavDobromyslov true. the question was about Long, not null

Comment: @SeanPatrickFloyd yep. Don't forget that Long variable value could be NULL sometimes.

Comment: So why is the 3rd option terrible? (For some reason, you  name the Integer variable "terrible".  Why? That's the option I'm using.

Comment: @user64141 Type casting in Java is a complicated issue. Casting Objects is fine, because you are actually not changing anything, just looking at the same object in a different way. But in this case, you have a chain of meaningful casts, from Object to primitive and then, through the madness of autoboxing, to object again, even though the syntax suggests it's another primitive. To me, this is a misuse of both boxing and primitive conversion. Not everything that can be done should be done.

Answer (score 59):

For non-null values:

```
Integer intValue = myLong.intValue();
```

Comment: Looks much cleaner than (int) (long) imo.

Comment: I use Long.valueOf(LONG_VARIABLE_HERE).intValue()

Comment: This does a narrowing primitive conversions from long to int (i.e. possible information loss since some bytes will have to be discarded)

Answer (score 20):

If you care to check for overflows and have [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) handy, there is [`Ints.checkedCast()`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/23.6-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.html#checkedCast%28long%29):

```
int theInt = Ints.checkedCast(theLong);
```

[The implementation](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/source/browse/guava/src/com/google/common/primitives/Ints.java#86) is dead simple, and throws [IllegalArgumentException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) on overflow:

```
public static int checkedCast(long value) {
  int result = (int) value;
  checkArgument(result == value, "Out of range: %s", value);
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 12):

If you are using Java 8 Do it as below

```
    import static java.lang.Math.toIntExact;

    public class DateFormatSampleCode {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            long longValue = 1223321L;
            int longTointValue = toIntExact(longValue);
            System.out.println(longTointValue);

        }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

You'll need to type cast it.

```
long i = 100L;
int k = (int) i;
```

Bear in mind that a long has a bigger range than an int so you might lose data.

If you are talking about the boxed types, then read the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#intValue%28%29).

Answer (score 10):

In Java 8 you can use [`Math.toIntExact`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toIntExact-long-). If you want to handle `null` values, use:

```
Integer intVal = longVal == null ? null : Math.toIntExact(longVal);
```

Good thing about this method is that it throws an [`ArithmeticException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ArithmeticException.html) if the argument (`long`) overflows an `int`.

Comment: why not we use the above statement as below :

Integer intVal = longVal != null ? Math.toIntExact(longVal) : null;

A usual practice

Answer (score 4):

The best simple way of doing so is:

```
public static int safeLongToInt( long longNumber ) 
    {
        if ( longNumber < Integer.MIN_VALUE || longNumber > Integer.MAX_VALUE ) 
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( longNumber + " cannot be cast to int without changing its value." );
        }
        return (int) longNumber;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming not null  longVal

```
Integer intVal = ((Number)longVal).intValue();
```

It works for example y you get an Object that can be an Integer or a Long. I know that is ugly, but it happens...

Answer (score 2):

Using toIntExact(long value) returns the value of the long argument, throwing an exception if the value overflows an int. it will work only API level 24 or above.

```
int id = Math.toIntExact(longId);
```

Answer (score 1):

long visitors =1000;

int convVisitors =(int)visitors;

Answer (score 0):

try this:

Int i = Long.valueOf(L)// L: Long Value

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note you are answering a very old and already answered question. Here is a guide on [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Thilo's accepted answer, `Math.toIntExact` works also great in Optional method chaining, despite it accepts only an `int` as an argument

```
Long coolLong = null;
Integer coolInt = Optional.ofNullable(coolLong).map(Math::toIntExact).orElse(0); //yields 0
```

Answer (score -3):

In java ,there is a rigorous way to convert a long to int

not only lnog can convert into int,any type of class extends Number can convert to other Number type in general,here I will show you how to convert a long to int,other type vice versa.

```
Long l = 1234567L;
int i = org.springframework.util.NumberUtils.convertNumberToTargetClass(l, Integer.class);
```

Comment: I think you forgot to create an abstract factory somewhere