# Casting Long to Integer throws ClassCastException

Tags: java, google-app-engine, exception, casting

Im trying to cast a long into int, but failed. I am use in a Servlet in Google App Engine if that matters.  I have did searches to [post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355303/how-can-i-convert-a-long-to-int-in-java) , [post2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804043/convert-long-into-integer)[docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) But no results
From my logs. point to this line:

```
//fields
private int multiplyer;
private Map<String, Object> mappings;



//the method
        Echo.log.info("key: "+WinningSetMappingEnum.multiplyer.toString()
        +"  value: "
        +mappings.get(WinningSetMappingEnum.multiplyer.toString())
        +"  "
        +mappings.get(WinningSetMappingEnum.multiplyer.toString()).getClass().getName()
                    );//For logging

         multiplyer=(Integer)mappings.get(MappingEnum.multiplyer.toString());//PROBLEM
```

LOG:

```
com.wtsang02.deserlizeMapping: key: multiplyer value: 0 java.lang.Long
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer
```

Comment: How didn't the linked posts help you?

Comment: The problem was map returned Object, stated in original question but the code tag didn't show up. Solution is Object->Long->long->int

Comment: @PaulBellora Its not dup, that is Long->Integer. See my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private Map<String, Object> mappings;
```

returns an Object. Therefore the solution is

```
long l = (Long) mappings.get(WinningSetMappingEnum.multiplyer
                .toString());
        multiplyer = (int) l;
```

Answer (score 3):

Both `Long` and `Integer` extend `java.lang.Number`.

How do you want to cast one class into another that is not related directly? What you can cast are the primitive values

```
  Integer i = (int) (myLong.longValue())
```

Although it would be easier to use the `intValue()` method in `Long`.