# Parsing an object attribute type to a different type?

Tags: java, parsing

I have 2 collections: product and inventory.  I am trying to enter new inventory for a store.

when I'm filling out inventory entry form I want the product number I enter to search the product list to resolve the correct name of the item.

I have a search method in my product collection but it takes an integer type.  The product number is of type long.

How can I convert the product number to an integer so the search will function correctly?

```
      //resolve product name to inventory item

      int idx = prodL.search(Integer.parseInt(prodNo));
      name = prodL.getProdName(idx);
```

Error: The method parseInt(java.lang.String) in the type java.lang.Integer is not applicable for the arguments (long)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert Long into Integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804043/convert-long-into-integer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
int idx = prodL.search((int)prodNo);
```

Please note this will truncate, so if prodno exceed Integer.MAX_VALUE, you will get some odd results.

Comment: That gives me this error: The method parseLong(java.lang.String) in the type java.lang.Long is not applicable for the arguments (long)

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap it in an `Integer` type and use `Integer.longValue()`