# an int value passed trhought intent return 0 on new activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, type-conversion

on the caller activity I have:

```
 protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {


          Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, sondaggioActivity.class);
          myIntent.putExtra("categoriaId", String.valueOf(id));
          MainActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
        // Toast.makeText(this, String.valueOf(id), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
```

the toast return the right value of the id of the item clicked on the list.
on the reciver activity i have:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.maindomanda);

        int category = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("categoriaId"); 
        TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.domanda);
        text.setText(String.valueOf(category));
    }
```

a very straight forward... the text field returns always 0... what i'm doing wrong? is the String.ValueOf() somehow deprecated? or is better to use something else...
and another side question... i pass the `long id` like i know what i'm doing, it's quite false... is it the so called "`_ID`" field? i get those values from a dbtable, is that that table ID?

Answer (score 2):

Change your code as:

```
String strcategory = getIntent().getExtras().getString("categoriaId");
```

because you are passing `String` from onListItemClick  to sondaggioActivity Activity and trying to receive as `Int`

**NOTE :**

Second and important point is `id` is `long` and you are trying to parsing it to `Int` which is also not valid .
see this post: [How can I convert a long to int in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355303/how-can-i-convert-a-long-to-int-in-java)

Solution is just send id as long from `onListItemClick` as

```
 myIntent.putExtra("categoriaId",id);
```

and receive it as in `sondaggioActivity` Activity :

```
long category = getIntent().getExtras().getLong("categoriaId");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting a int `getInt("categoriaId")`, you passed in a string `putExtra("categoriaId", String.valueOf(id));`
String.valueOf(); returns a STring representation of the int.

Answer (score 0):

pass categoriaId as long myIntent.putExtra("categoriaId", id);