# Cannot convert from long to int, why can't I round this double to the nearest int using Math.round

Tags: java, math, double, rounding

why can't I round this double to the nearest int using Math.round, I get this error "cannot convert from long to int"

```
    Double bat_avg = Double.parseDouble(data[4])/Double.parseDouble(data[2]);
    int ibat_avg = Math.round(bat_avg*1000.00);
    System.out.println(bat_avg);
```

Comment: [`Math.round` returns a `long`.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(double))

Comment: You need to cast it into an int. (int) Math.round(...)

Comment: Yes, you can cast it to int, but you have to take into account this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355303/how-can-i-convert-a-long-to-int-in-java.

Answer (score 3):

You can use float instead:

```
Float bat_avg = Float.parseFloat(data[4]) / Float.parseFloat(data[2]);
int ibat_avg = Math.round(bat_avg * 1000.00f);
System.out.println(bat_avg);
```

---

There are two versions of `Math.round`:

- `Math.round(double d)` which returns `long`.
- `Math.round(float)` which returns `int`.

Comment: It's better to use `round` on an argument of type `double` and convert the result to `int` than to use `float` to the conversion unless the best representation of the value to be converted is a `float`.  Given `float f=1234567.875f;`, the value of `round(f*1000.0f)` will be 1234567936.  The original value was precisely representable, and the arithmetically-correct result of 1234567875 would be representable as `int`, but the result won't be a different value.  Multiplying by 1000.0 would fix that.

Answer (score 2):

[`Math.round(double)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29) will return a long, which can't be implicitly casted as you would lose precision. You have to explicitly cast it to an int:

```
int ibat_avg = (int)Math.round(bat_avg*1000.00);
```

Answer (score 1):

Math.round(Double) returns a long.  Math.round(float) returns an int.

So the two solutions are

```
int ibat_avg = Math.round((float) bat_avg*1000.00);
```

or

```
int ibat_avg = (int) Math.round(bat_avg*1000.00);
```