# casting to int while using Math.round(double d) in Java 1.8.0_152

Tags: java, math, casting, java-8, rounding

I don't understand why code snippet 1 works fine, but code snippet 2 gives compile time error `incompatible types: java.lang.Long cannot be converted to int`

Is related to priority of casting in java? I went through this [thread on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16754634/cannot-convert-from-long-to-int-why-cant-i-round-this-double-to-the-nearest-in), but it didn't help.

Please explain in detail what happens behind the scenes in the both the snippets and why it doesn't give error in code snippet 1.

**Code snippet 1:**

```
package com.company;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double dbl = 10.25;
        int i1 = (int)Math.round(dbl);
    }
}
```

**Code snippet 2:**

```
package com.company;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double dbl = 10.25;
        Long lng = Math.round(dbl);
        int i2 = (int)lng;
    }
}
```

Comment: [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36331461/3148590)

Comment: `int` and `long` and `double` are primitives, they can be casted. `Integer`, `Long`, `Double` are Objects, no cast possible.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514958/how-does-double-to-int-cast-work-in-java

Comment: Check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30776256/casting-rules-for-primitive-types-in-java) which lists the rules for casting primitives.  It looks like `long` to `int` is an allowed narrowing cast.

Comment: @Zabuza you made my day. Now I understood what's the issue. So if the use `long` in snippet #1 instead of `Long`, it would work. My goodness!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a closer look at what happens. In **snippet 1**:

```
double dbl = 10.25;
int i1 = (int) Math.round(dbl);
```

You declare a `double`. The result after rounding is a `long`. Then comes a cast to `int` which is possible since both are **primitive types**, Java allows the cast. Then you store this inside `int`.

---

In **snippet 2** however things change a bit:

```
double dbl = 10.25;
Long lng = Math.round(dbl);
int i2 = (int) lng;
```

You declare a `double`, round returns a `long` but you want to store it inside `Long`. So Java automatically transforms `long` into `Long`, this is called **auto-boxing**. Java can box all primitive types to their wrapper classes.

Last you try to cast `Long` to `int` but this is not possible since `Long` is an object now. It can however automatically unbox `Long` to `long`. From there you can go to `int`. Let's first take a look at those two variants:

```
int i2 = (long) lng;           // Make unboxing explicit by casting
int i2 = lng.longValue()       // Use unboxing method
```

However it won't compile either due to:

> incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from long to int

So the conversion is possible but the compiler warns us that a `long` could possibly **not fit into** an `int` (lossy conversion), thus it prevents us from doing so.

We can however do the conversion by again making it **explicit** by casting:

```
int i2 = (int) lng.longValue() // The whole process completely explicit
```

Or if you have **Java 8**, use `Math#toIntExact` ([documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#toIntExact-long-)) which will throw an `ArithmeticException` if the `long` doesn't fit into the `int`:

```
int i2 = Math.toIntExact(lng.longValue());
```

Note that Java won't unbox your `Long` to `long` and then cast it to `int` automatically, you will need to make the unboxing explicit on your own, as shown.

It's simply one of the **casting rules** of the **JVM**, in this case probably to prevent unintentional programming errors.

Comment: The result after rounding is **not double**. Infact, it returns `long`. Please refer https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round-double-

Comment: @AnV Oh, of course. Thanks, corrected.

Comment: @Holger Yeah, due to *lossy conversion*. Edited the answer, thanks.