# Convert an int array to long array using Java 8?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I have tried few ways unsuccessfully.

`this.tileUpdateTimes` is `long[]` and `other.tileUpdateTimes` is `int[]`

```
this.tileUpdateTimes = Arrays.stream(other.tileUpdateTimes).toArray(size -> new long[size]);
this.tileUpdateTimes = Arrays.stream(other.tileUpdateTimes)
            .map(item -> ((long) item)).toArray();
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You need to use the [`mapToLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#mapToLong-java.util.function.IntToLongFunction-) operation.

```
int[] intArray = {1, 2, 3};
long[] longArray = Arrays.stream(intArray).mapToLong(i -> i).toArray();
```

or, as [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) points out, in this case, you can directly use [`asLongStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#asLongStream--):

```
int[] intArray = {1, 2, 3};
long[] longArray = Arrays.stream(intArray).asLongStream().toArray();
```

---

The `map` method on primitive streams return a stream of the same primitive type. In this case, [`IntStream.map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#map-java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator-) will still return an `IntStream`.

The cast to `long` with

```
.map(item -> ((long) item))
```

will actually make the code not compile since the mapper used in `IntStream.map` is expected to return an `int` and [you need an explicit cast to convert from the new casted `long` to `int`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355303/how-can-i-convert-a-long-to-int-in-java).

With `.mapToLong(i -> i)`, which expects a mapper returning a `long`, the `int i` value [is promoted](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) to `long` automatically, so you don't need a cast.

Comment: how will you do the same from short[] to Int[] ?

Comment: @EladBenda There is no `ShortStream` in the stream API, so you wouldn't use it for that task. You can use a traditional for loop though.

Comment: The `.mapToLong(i -> i)` step is obsolete as the conversion from `int` to `long` can be handled intrinsically: `Arrays.stream(intArray).asLongStream().toArray()`…

Comment: @Holger I think I never noticed that method. Thanks!

Comment: The key thing is avoiding boxing of the primitive types. So, probably asLongStream is a bit better because it avoids doing a lot of boxing/unboxing for the map call.

Comment: @JillesvanGurp There won't be any boxing with `mapToLong`, the mapper accepts an `int` and returns a `long`, keeping primitive types. Reading the code `asLongStream()` is only short-hand for `mapToLong(i -> i)`, but it makes it a bit clearer and avoids creating a lambda.

Answer (score 4):

This snippet compiles fine for me and returns the expected result:

```
    int[] iarr = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
    long[] larr = Arrays.stream(iarr)
                        .mapToLong((i) -> (long) i)
                        .toArray();
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(larr));
```