# Convert long array to int array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, types, int, long-integer

I've just begun using java and I can't convert a long array type to int array. Can you give a piece of advice what should I do?
Thank you!

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        long[] numbers;
        numbers = sorting(new long[]{5, 21, 19, 55, 94, 73, 69, 100,});



    }

    public static long[] sorting(long [] numbers) {

        for (long num : numbers) {
            long j = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length - 1; i++) {
                if (numbers[i] > numbers[i + 1]) {
                    j = numbers[i];
                    numbers[i] = numbers[i + 1];
                    numbers[i + 1] = j;


                }
            }
            System.out.println(num + ",");
        }
        return (numbers);
```

Comment: Do you want to convert the `long` array to `int` array?

Answer (score 2):

To convert an long[] to int[], you need to iterate over your long[] array, cast each individual number to int and put it to the int[] array.

```
// Your result
long[] numbers = sorting(new long[] {5, 21, 19, 55, 94, 73, 69, 100});

// Define a new int array with the same length of your result array
int[] intNumbers = new int[numbers.length];

// Loop through all the result numbers
for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
{
    // Cast to int and put it to the int array
    intNumbers[i] = (int) numbers[i];
}
```

Or you can also use Java Streams (>= 1.8) for a shorter version:

`int[] intArray = Arrays.stream(numbers).mapToInt(i -> (int) i).toArray();`

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar question in 
[convert-an-int-array-to-long-array-using-java-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37882512/convert-an-int-array-to-long-array-using-java-8)

You can try this:

```
    long[] longArray = {1, 2, 3};
    int[] intArray = Arrays.stream(longArray).mapToInt(i -> (int) i).toArray();
```

Comment: Yes, but this does not work, because i needs to be converted to int first.

Answer (score 0):

Something else to mention here. If you just cast `long` to `int` you risk an integer overflow. So to be safe I would recommend `Math#toIntExact` function which ensures the conversion is safe. Here is an example:

```
long[] longs = new long[] {1,2,3,4,5};
int[] ints = Arrays.stream(longs).mapToInt(Math::toIntExact).toArray();
```

If `longs` contains a value that can't be converted to an `int` then an
`ArithmeticException` will be thrown e.g.

```
long[] longs = new long[] {1,2,3,4,5, Long.MAX_VALUE};
int[] ints = Arrays.stream(longs).mapToInt(Math::toIntExact).toArray(); // Throws here
```

will throw `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: integer overflow` this ensures your code works correctly.