# Counting same words in the list by using Streams

Tags: java, list, collections, java-8, java-stream

how to count specific words in the list and return it as *int*

```
strings.stream().filter(element -> element.equals("")).count();
```

returns *long*.

If shortly, how to write this code by using *stream*?

```
private static int getCountEmptyStringLoop(List<String> strings) {
        int counter = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < strings.size(); i++) {
            if (strings.get(i).equals("")){
                counter++;
            }
        }
        return counter;
    }
```

I began to learn streams and I don't really understand how it works.

Comment: The count() of interface Stream returns long, there is no standard implementation returning int. Hence you can just [convert long to int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355303/how-can-i-convert-a-long-to-int-in-java) - of course being careful for the potential too-large size of the .count() result

Comment: You better use `"".equals(element)` than `element.equals("")`. In the first case, the `null` string will be processed correctly.  Second code will throw an exception if the `element == null`.

Comment: @chptr-one Yes, exactly. That's much safer.

Comment: Just use [`Collections.frequency(strings, "")`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#frequency(java.util.Collection,java.lang.Object)) which is the simplest approach, returns an `int`, and exists since JDK 1.5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just manually cast the count to `int`:

```java
private static int getCountEmptyStringLoop(List<String> strings) {
    return (int) strings.stream()
                        .filter(""::equals)
                        .count();
}
```

or

```java
private static int getCountEmptyStringLoop(List<String> strings) {
    return (int) strings.stream()
                        .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                        .filter(String::isEmpty)
                        .count();
}
```

Comment: `.filter(String::isEmpty)`

Comment: @AniketSahrawat This will require null check first. Otherwise its error-prone.

Comment: Java11 onwards, [`String::isBlank`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#isBlank()) is the recommended function.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash `String::isBlank` has a little bit different semantics than `String::isEmpty`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using [`count()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#count--), which will return `long`.

Please, try instead:

```java
int count = words.stream()
  .mapToInt(word -> "".equals(word) ? 1 : 0)
  .sum()
;
```

Or:

```java
int count = words.stream()
  .map(word -> "".equals(word) ? 1 : 0)
  .reduce(0, (a, b) -> a + b)
;
```

Very similar:

```java
int count = words.stream()
  .map(word -> "".equals(word) ? 1 : 0)
  .reduce(0, Integer::sum)
;
```

Or using collectors:

```java
int count = words.stream()
  .map(word -> "".equals(word) ? 1 : 0)
  .collect(Collectors.summingInt(Integer::intValue))
;
```

Or, much better, in one row, as suggested by @Holger:

```java
int count = words.stream()
  .collect(Collectors.summingInt(word -> "".equals(word) ? 1 : 0))
;
```

All these examples can be enclosed in a method, more general, like this:

```java
import java.util.Objects;

//...

public int getCount(List<String> terms, String searchTerm) {
  Objects.requireNonNull(terms, "Null terms list provided");

  int count = terms.stream()
      .mapToInt(word -> Objects.equals(searchTerm, word)? 1 : 0)
      .sum();
  ;
  
  return count;
}
```

In your use case:

```java
int countOfEmptyString = getCount(words, "");
```

As a side note, to avoid npe issues and `null` checking, always compare the information like this (`""` will never be `null`):

```java
"".equals(element)
```

Instead of (`element` can be `null`):

```java
element.equals("")
```

By the way, the @ETO answer is a very suitable alternative as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static <T> long countTokens(List<T> list, T token) {
     return list.stream().filter(item -> item.equals(token)).count();
}
```