# Casting a long to an Int returns in '-1'?

Tags: java

Is it safe to cast a long to an int in Java?

For some reason, the following code , I get '-1' as anIntVar. And I have checked 'aLongVar' is not an -1.

```
public static final long CONST = 1000 * 62;

long aLongVar
int anIntVar =  (int)(aLongVar/ CONST);
```

Comment: You mean aside from the fact that a long holds more information that would be lost in the conversion to int?

Comment: possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590831/safely-casting-long-to-int-in-java

Comment: This code does not even compile.

Comment: Well what *is* the value of `aLongVar`?

Comment: Please post working code examples....

Comment: I think `aLongVar` is `-62000` thus equaling `-1` ! :P

Comment: Or maybe it was 532575944642000. Then divide by 62000 gives 8589934591, which in hex is 1FFFFFFFF. Cast to an int and you have -1.

Comment: What is the value of aLongVar ? We can't assign a default value of 0L to it, since it will result the o/p as 0.

Comment: @Jay, hahahaha, but you're not casting from hex to an int? You are casting from 8589934591 to an int. ;-)

Comment: @Nideo: Decimal and hex are just display formats. The underlying number is the same either way. There is no such thing as a Java or a C "hex integer" as opposed to a "decimal integer".

Comment: @Jay, I know that - but try `long x = 8589934591;` and say `x/62000` - that would not equal `-1` .

Comment: @Nideo: Wait, I said to cast the 8589934591, not divide again. Try this: long x=532575944642000L; long q=x/62000L; int n=(int) q; Then q will be 8589934591. n will be -1.

Comment: @Nideo: Or try simply this: int n=(int) 4294967338L; System.out.println(n); It will display "42".

Comment: Cool! Did not know :) I only work with int's and double's ... sometimes float - but I have no working-knowledge of long.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, its not safe. Don't do it.  Because, A `Long / long` has **64 bit** and can hold much more data than an `Integer / int` has **32 bit** only. Doing the conversion will result in loss  of information.

If at all you wish to do it, do like this

Use the `.intValue()` to convert the `Long` value to an `int` value.

Answer (score 2):

If it was safe it wouldn't require an explicit cast.

Answer (score 1):

A `long` is 64 bits, and an `int` is 32 bits, so no, it's not safe.

Comment: What do you mean by 'not safe'? The fact that the last few digits will be lost?

Comment: @Nideo: By that I mean that in general it's a bad idea to do that, because of what you said, or because of the fact that if the `long` contains a value that's larger than the maximum value for `int`, there could be garbage after the cast.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
int anIntVar = Math.rint(aLongVar);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast a long to an int and get meaningful results if the value in the long will fit in an int. If not, you will get high bits truncated. In your example you don't show what was in the numerator before you did the division, but -1 is certainly not an impossible value given the right inputs.

Is it legal? Yes. Is it safe? No, not unless you do range checks, or are confident that you know your inputs well enough.