# How to trigger CSS "hover state" using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, browser

CSS's "hovered state" will trigger when the user hovers over an element:

```
<style>
.element{

}
.element:hover{
    background-color:red;
}
</style>
```

How can we set the element to "hovered state" using Javascript?

Is it possible?

Comment: Seems like you taking a hammer to stick what apears to be not a nail. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: like when do you want to trigger it??

Comment: @Balanivash: nevermind that. Why does he want to trigger hover on it's own? Why shouldn't he copy-paste the style and use element.className = 'newClass'?

Comment: Here's my use case: I'm mirroring a page over WebSockets using DOM Mutation Observers. `:hover` state is not in the DOM so need some other generic way to handle it.

Comment: @the_drow, Have a trip to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590831/safely-casting-long-to-int-in-java#comment-11386801

Comment: @Balanivash, I want to trigger it using Javascript on a certain event unrelated to user's input. This can be a timing event or something else altogether.

Comment: @Pacerier: think you can do this use jQuery like `$(<element>).trigger('mouseenter');`

Comment: @Balanivash, I only use Vanilla-JS, no jquery.

Comment: Please check this [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226676/how-do-i-simulate-a-mouseover-in-pure-javascript-that-activates-the-css-hover]

Comment: @the_drow I’m writing unit tests for CSS using https://github.com/studio-b12/tape-css. I’m facing exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

If you could accept using `:focus` instead of hover, you can use:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
links[0].focus();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/RceFU/).

Or

```
var linkToFocus = document.getElementById('link');
linkToFocus.focus();
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/RceFU/1/).

This approach, obviously, requires adapting your CSS to include the `a:focus` style:

```
a:link, a:visited {
    background-color: #fff;
}
a:hover, a:focus, a:active {
    background-color: #f00;
}
```

Comment: But why would one do such a thing?

Comment: @the_drow: I have absolutely no idea; but I'd suspect that it's to show/highlight something on page-load, maybe? There are better ways of doing that, of course, but without further information I can only try to answer the question that was asked. Irrespective of the use-case, sadly.

Comment: Good answer, but the question asked how to trigger ":hover", not ":focus".

Comment: @the_drow: This could be useful when creating a components-demo-page, where you want to show the different button styles in their different states (neutral, disabled, hovered, focused, active).

Comment: @the_drow This could be used for example when you want to quickly automate minor tasks via the DevTools wherein additional elements are only revealed/added to DOM when hovered.

Comment: Im here looking for this solution myself.  A client needs an ability to wrap many Shortcodes in a Drupal CMS with the ability of a parent element to take the link from a deeper child anchor and activate it, but to show the hover state of the anchor. unfortunately there are no classes for the hover effect it's all :hover and all old code. Normally its a case of wrap the whole thing with an anchor with a fake button inside but the old site structure dictates otherwise :-P

Answer (score 32):

You're probably better off duplicating the :hover styles into another class and then just adding that class name to the element when you want them to change permanently. Pseudo-classes are "pseudo" for a reason.

Comment: This is what I'm doing right now and am looking for better alternatives.

Comment: I'm not sure what definition of "better" you're looking for. Dynamically triggering a class through JavaScript should use a proper class and not a pseud-class. The entire purpose for `:hover` is to *only* be used when a user hovers over an element. This is expressly why JavaScript methods like the Element.classList (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) collection exist.

Comment: That's solving the problem the wrong way. The problem is I need to activate `:hover` and the straightforward solution would be a command to do **exactly that**.

Comment: Without explicitly instructing a user to mouse over a DOM element *you can't* trigger :hover. See the accepted answer here for a technical explanation as to why. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17226676/how-do-i-simulate-a-mouseover-in-pure-javascript-that-activates-the-css-hover]

Comment: @Pacerier did you find a solution that worked for you? Curious to know how you solved this.

Comment: I used a function that applies the style to the element. Needs extra work, but I'll not pollute the global namespace.

Comment: That doesn't explain it. It begs the question **Why** is hover not a trusted event?

Comment: Not being a member of the W3C I can only hazard a guess, but this article (http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/11/12/an-introduction-to-dom-events/) on Smashing Magazine sheds a little light: _An event is said to be “trusted” when it originates from the device itself, not synthesized from within JavaScript._ You're trying to simulate a hover event rather than it being triggered naturally. Of course you can simulate click events without actually tapping on a mouse button easily enough so it's not a hard standard obviously. Browsers are more forgiving with click but not with hover, apparently.

Comment: Exactly, it seems totally arbitrary that we are allowed to call "focus" but not "hover".

Comment: I would assume that hover (and combined with click or mouse up & down for drag & drop), could behave or appear like hijacking a user's system (if you ignore automation cases), so it is not ideal to support. Click I can't say, but focus would allow auto-focus to a target form field or element the site designer wants the user to focus on say for example a text field with missing or incorrect data (e.g. form field validation checks). But that's just my assumptions.

Comment: @Pacerier in my case, I need to traverse a list of li using arrow keys and have the same css as it would have if it would hover. So I end up using focus from my JS instead of handling the hover event, which wouldn't be triggered in the scenario of keyboard traversal.