# iframe doesn't load until after hover

Tags: html, iframe, google-sheets

I am using an iframe to publish an interactive chart from Google Sheets. The iframe will not load on the page until I hover over it with a mouse. (Tested with latest chrome browser on desktop and mobile)

Workaround experiment: I changed the iframe from interactive mode to image and the iframe loads immediately.

```
iframe frameborder="0" height="371" id="chartframe" scrolling="no" seamless="" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRUJ3BujnYfrxc4FCgIfcCg58qEtuaaHRtFZ33MaM-tn4nemyxbp4i3usiJdwHPkXqOn9V-RcpqdLQe/pubchart?oid=197457924&amp;format=interactive" width="570"
```

Expected: Up until a couple a days ago the iframe for the charts in interactive mode would load within a few seconds. This has been the behavior for several years.

Issue: Then with no changes to my side, all interactive iframes for all charts across multiple websites & platforms and from multiple sheets fail to display until I hover over the chart area when using interactive mode.

(HTML snip shown is what worked fine until a couple of days ago.)

Comment: maybe another workaround could be trigerring this hover state using some jscode [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406976/how-to-trigger-css-hover-state-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

I started seeing this exact behavior recently as well.

It happens with Chrome, Safari, and Firefox (at least).

Here's my iframe code:

```
<iframe width="550" height="550" seamless frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQC5Xml_m97eBQfjXeoG9ZP5U-ApXSiDJI7eYYqXzw7tyFBDmVDG5sbLxOoo5O29LOEM0EE21xTfthq/pubchart?oid=525571464&amp;format=interactive"></iframe>
```

Is yours a SquareSpace website (mine is)?

Comment: my websites are in two difference locations, blogger and hosted in Google Cloud. So doesn't seem to depend on the host.