# ResultSet convert to int from query

Tags: java, sql, jakarta-ee, resultset

So I am trying to get the result as count from a sql query as follows

```
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT count(employeeID) FROM employee WHERE " +
                "employeeID='"+_empID+"' AND password = '"+_password + "'");
```

so i am also trying to convert that value to int and I tried the follwing

```
 for (; rs.next();) {
val =  (Integer) rs.getObject(1);
}
```

I have also try

```
val = Integer.parseInt(rs.getObject(1));
```

but nothing I get the following errors

java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer

How can I do this.. so if that returns a 0,3 or 4 that it becomes an integer?

Thank you

EDITED TO: (STILL GETTING ERROR)

```
    long countLong = 0; 

        for (; rs.next();) {
           countLong = rs.getLong(1);
        }


       if(countLong < 1)
       {
         isAuthentic = false;
       }
       else
       {
         isAuthentic = true;
       }
```

Comment: This question was already asked, take a look.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590831/safely-casting-long-to-int-in-java

Comment: Hello Jon, that did not help me.. I need to know how to get the value of the result set (database) and then make it something i can use to evaluate

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A good trick to use when you are not sure about the *exact* number type is to cast it to the parent class of all numeric type, `Number`:

```
val =  ((Number) rs.getObject(1)).intValue();
```

This will work for all numeric types, eg `float`, `long`, `int` etc.

Answer (score 1):

Use `ResultSet.getLong` method:

```
long countLong = resultSet.getLong(1);
//if you really want and you are sure that it fits you can now cast
int count = (int)countLong;
```

Comment: No i am still getting that error java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer (see how I modified the code)

Comment: @user710502: your code is OK now. Maybe you miss recompilation? Please attach stacktrace.

Comment: Thak you for your help to zacheusz

Answer (score 0):

Try a getString() and then Long.parseLong().

Answer (score 0):

Cast it to a string and then to an int or long or whatever you want:

```
Integer.parseInt(rs.getObject(1).toString());
```