# SWIG (v1.3.29) generated C++ to Java Vector class not acting properly

Tags: java, c++, vector, java-native-interface, swig

I have some native C++ code that I'm converting to Java using SWIG so that my Java application can use it. In particular there are some functions that return std::vector. Here's a snippet of my interface file:

```
%include "std_vector.i"
namespace std {
  %template(Vector) vector<double>;
  %template(Matrix) vector<vector<double> >;
}

%include "std_string.i"
```

`std_string.i` and `std_vector.i` were included in my build of SWIG I'm using. My first surprise  was that the Java output included SWIG's "own" version of the Vector class (as opposed to using `java.util.Vector`). My real issue is that the Vectors that get returned from these functions do not seem to work. For example I cannot retrieve their contents using `get()` (sometimes crashing the program) or the `size()` function returning negative values. I know the `Vector`s contain data because I coded 'String' versions of the same functions which simply iterate through the `Vector`s (back in the native C++ code) and return the contents in a comma separated `String` value. While this is a valid workaround, ultimately I would like this to work properly with me being able to receive and manipulate the `Vectors`. Any helps/tips would be much appreciated.

Comment: Not a SWIG user, but looking at `std_vector.i` (the versions of it I find online, anyway), `size()` is supposed to be an `unsigned int`, and SWIG is supposed to translate that to a Java `long`. If you're getting negative sizes, are they pure nonsense, or do they look like they might be mistreating `unsigned` as signed?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The appropriate base type for wrapping `std::vector` in Java is `java.util.AbstractList`. Using `java.util.Vector` as a base would be odd because you'd end up with two sets of storage, one in the `std::vector`, and one in the `java.util.Vector`.

The reason SWIG doesn't do this for you though is because [you can't have `AbstractList<double>` in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721546/why-dont-generics-support-primitive-types), it has to be `AbstractList<Double>` (`Double` inherits from `Object` whereas `double` is a primitive type).

Having said all that I've put together a small example that wraps `std::vector<double>` and `std::vector<std::vector<double> >` nicely in Java. It's not complete, but it supports the "for each" style of iteration in Java and `set()`/`get()` on elements. It should be sufficient to show how to implement other things as/when you want them.

I'll talk through the interface file in sections as we go, but basically it'll all be sequential and complete.

Starting with `num.i` which defines our module `num`:

```
%module num

%{
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

std::vector<double> testVec() {
  return std::vector<double>(10,1.0);
}

std::vector<std::vector<double> > testMat() {
  return std::vector<std::vector<double> >(10, testVec());
}
%}

%pragma(java) jniclasscode=%{
  static {
    try {
        System.loadLibrary("num");
    } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {
      System.err.println("Native code library failed to load. \n" + e);
      System.exit(1);
    }
  }
%}
```

We have `#include`s for the generated `num_wrap.cxx` and two implementations of functions for testing (they could be in a separate file I just put them here out of laziness/convenience).

There's also a trick there with the `%pragma(java) jniclasscode=` that I like to use in Java SWIG interfaces to cause the shared object/DLL to be loaded transparently for the user of the interface.

Next up in the interface file is the parts of `std::vector` we want to wrap. I'm not using `std_vector.i` because we need to make a few changes:

```
namespace std {

    template<class T> class vector {
      public:
        typedef size_t size_type;
        typedef T value_type;
        typedef const value_type& const_reference;
        %rename(size_impl) size;
        vector();
        vector(size_type n);
        size_type size() const;
        size_type capacity() const;
        void reserve(size_type n);
        %rename(isEmpty) empty;
        bool empty() const;
        void clear();
        void push_back(const value_type& x);
        %extend {
            const_reference get_impl(int i) throw (std::out_of_range) {
                // at will throw if needed, swig will handle
                return self->at(i);
            }
            void set_impl(int i, const value_type& val) throw (std::out_of_range) {
                // at can throw
                self->at(i) = val;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

The main change here is `%rename(size_impl) size;`, which tells SWIG to expose `size()` from `std::vector` as `size_impl` instead. We need to do this because Java expects `size` to return an `int` where as the `std::vector` version returns a `size_type` which more than likely won't be `int`.

Next up in the interface file we tell it what base class and interfaces we want to implement as well as writing some extra Java code to coerce things between functions with incompatible types:

```
%typemap(javabase) std::vector<double> "java.util.AbstractList<Double>"
%typemap(javainterface) std::vector<double> "java.util.RandomAccess"
%typemap(javacode) std::vector<double> %{
  public Double get(int idx) {
    return get_impl(idx);
  }
  public int size() {
    return (int)size_impl();
  }
  public Double set(int idx, Double d) {
    Double old = get_impl(idx);
    set_impl(idx, d.doubleValue());
    return old;
  }

%}

%typemap(javabase) std::vector<std::vector<double> > "java.util.AbstractList<Vector>"
%typemap(javainterface) std::vector<std::vector<double> > "java.util.RandomAccess"
%typemap(javacode) std::vector<std::vector<double> > %{
  public Vector get(int idx) {
    return get_impl(idx);
  }
  public int size() {
    return (int)size_impl();
  }
  public Vector set(int idx, Vector v) {
    Vector old = get_impl(idx);
    set_impl(idx, v);
    return old;
  }

%}
```

This sets a base class of `java.util.AbstractList<Double>` for `std::vector<double>` and `java.util.AbstractList<Vector>` for `std::vector<std::vector<double> >` (`Vector` is what we will be calling `std::vector<double>` on the Java side of the interface).

We also supply an implementation of `get` and `set` on the Java side which can handle the `double` to `Double` conversion and back again.

Lastly in the interface we add:

```
namespace std {
  %template(Vector) std::vector<double>;
  %template(Matrix) std::vector<vector<double> >;
}

std::vector<double> testVec();
std::vector<std::vector<double> > testMat();
```

This tells SWIG to refer to `std::vector<double>` (with the specific type) as `Vector` and similarly for `std::vector<vector<double> >` as `Matrix`. We also tell SWIG to expose our two test functions.

Next up, `test.java`, a simple `main` in Java to exercise our code a little:

```
import java.util.AbstractList;

public class test {
  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    Vector v = num.testVec();
    AbstractList<Double> l = v;
    for (Double d: l) {
      System.out.println(d);
    }
    Matrix m = num.testMat();
    m.get(5).set(5, new Double(5.0));
    for (Vector col: m) {
      for (Double d: col) {
        System.out.print(d + " ");
      }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

To build and run this we do:

```
swig -java -c++ num.i
g++ -Wall -Wextra num_wrap.cxx -shared -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/include -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-6-sun/include/linux/ -o libnum.so

javac test.java && LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. java test
```

I tested this with g++ version 4.4 and SWIG 1.3.40 on Linux/x86.

The complete version of `num.i` can be found [here](http://users.aber.ac.uk/ajw/num.i), but can always be reconstructed from this answer by pasting each of the part together into one file.

Things I've not implemented from `AbstractList`:

1. `add()` - can be implemented via `push_back()`, std_vector.i even tries to implement something compatible by default, but it doesn't work with the `Double` vs `double` problem or match the return type specified in `AbstractList` (Don't forget to increment [`modCount`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html#modCount))
2. `remove()` - not great for `std::vector` in terms of time complexity, but not impossible to implement either (likewise with `modCount`)
3. A constructor which takes another `Collection` is recommended, but not implemented here. Can be implemented at the same place `set()` and `get()` are, but will need `$javaclassname` to name the generated constructor correctly.
4. You might want to use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590831/safely-casting-long-to-int-in-java) to check that the `size_type`->`int` conversion in `size()` is sane.

Comment: This is quite nice and really impressive, although I was hoping for insight into the crashing problem. I'm seeing crashes on the Linux64 version of an app that works solidly on 32-bit architectures, and I'm wondering about possible lurking bugs in std_vector.i itself.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill - I can't see anything obvious in the `std_vector.i` on my version of SWIG that would cause such a behaviour. My guess would be either an incorrect mapping between the native Java types and some type elsewhere in the wrapped C++, or possibly a problem elsewhere more generally. I can't really make much of an informed guess beyond that though I'm afraid. I'll test this out on a Linux/x86_64 machine shortly though. I hope what I've written will be useful to others looking at wrapping C++ containers for Java using SWIG though.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill - I can't reproduce the problem you've reported - can you put together a minimal working example for it perhaps? A small module that shows the crashing problem more clearly would be very helpful.

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill - have you seen http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html#jvm64? Looks like that might well be related. It seems there was some code checked in not too long after 1.3.29 related to this, but the wrapper I suggested should work well too.

Comment: thanks for continuing to think about this problem! I'm back to work tomorrow morning, and I'll see what I can do. I never actually explained my particular issue in detail (this isn't my question, remember!) and the circumstances are actually more complicated, but the hint about sizeof(long) is potentially useful. The problem I'm seeing is compiler-dependent.

Comment: fyi, I found my solution, posted as a new answer to this question.

Answer (score 4):

I'm the person who offered the bounty on this question because I had the same issue. I'm a bit embarrassed to report that I've finally found the real solution -- and it's in the SWIG manual! The fix is to use the `-fno-strict-aliasing` flag for `g++` when compiling the generated code -- simple as that. I hate to admit that it took a lot of Googling to finally found this out.

The problem is that recent versions of `g++` do some aggressive optimizations that make assumptions about pointer aliasing that don't hold for the code SWIG generates for `std_vector` (and in other cases.) `g++` 4.1 doesn't do this, but 4.4.5 definitely does. The assumptions are perfectly valid and allowed by the current ISO standard, although I'm not sure how well known they are. Basically, it's that two pointers of different types (with a few exceptions) can *never* point to the same address. The code that SWIG generates to convert between pointer-to-object and `jlong` falls afoul of this rule.