# Debugging Java JVM Crashes - Native Code Access

Tags: java, debugging, java-native-interface

Anyone have any ideas what is causing the below JVM crash?  I'm using java 6 and Windows 32 bit.  I'm trying to access native (JNI) C APIs.  I can access some of them, but a few cause the below crash.

**C APIs Referenced in crashes below:**

```
int wrapOpenSession1(int two, char *host, char *localhost, int udpport, int one){
    return 1;
}

int wrapOpenSession5(char *host, char *localhost){
    return 1;
}
```

**JNI Code (generated using SWIG):**

```
package com.test.ewapi.jni;

public class Sample {

  public static int wrapOpenSession1(int two, String host, String localhost, int udpport, int one) {
    return SampleJNI.wrapOpenSession1(two, host, localhost, udpport, one);
  }


  public static int wrapOpenSession5(String host, String localhost) {
    return SampleJNI.wrapOpenSession5(host, localhost);
  }
}

package com.test.ewapi.jni;

public class SampleJNI {
  public final static native int wrapOpenSession1(int jarg1, String jarg2, String jarg3, int jarg4, int jarg5);
  public final static native int wrapOpenSession5(String jarg1, String jarg2);
}
```

**JVM Crash w/o Xcheck:jin**

```
    #

# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0054fc83, pid=912, tid=3428
#
# JRE version: 6.0_30-b12
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.5-b03 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0054fc83
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x01861c00):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=3428, stack(0x00500000,0x00550000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, writing address 0xac338cd8

Registers:
EAX=0x01861d28, EBX=0x338d3eb8, ECX=0x7c34218f, EDX=0x0000000c
ESP=0x0054fc30, EBP=0x0054fc78, ESI=0x338d3eb8, EDI=0x01861c00
EIP=0x0054fc83, EFLAGS=0x00210287

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0054fc30)
0x0054fc30:   01861d28 0054fc70 0054fc7c 0054fc78
0x0054fc40:   0054fc74 6d90311e 0054fc48 338d3eb8
0x0054fc50:   0054fc7c 338d48b8 00000000 338d3eb8
0x0054fc60:   00000000 0054fc78 0054fca0 01962f45
0x0054fc70:   338d4858 019682d9 338d4bb0 338d4b80
0x0054fc80:   0054fc80 338cccaa 0054fcac 338cd988
0x0054fc90:   00000000 338cccb0 0054fc78 0054fca8
0x0054fca0:   0054fcd0 01962f45 338d4bb0 338d4b80 

Instructions: (pc=0x0054fc83)
0x0054fc63:   00 78 fc 54 00 a0 fc 54 00 45 2f 96 01 58 48 8d
0x0054fc73:   33 d9 82 96 01 b0 4b 8d 33 80 4b 8d 33 80 fc 54
0x0054fc83:   00 aa cc 8c 33 ac fc 54 00 88 d9 8c 33 00 00 00
0x0054fc93:   00 b0 cc 8c 33 78 fc 54 00 a8 fc 54 00 d0 fc 54 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x01861d28 is an unknown value
EBX=0x338d3eb8 is an oop
{method} 
 - klass: {other class}
ECX=0x7c34218f is an unknown value
EDX=0x0000000c is an unknown value
ESP=0x0054fc30 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x01861c00
EBP=0x0054fc78 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x01861c00
ESI=0x338d3eb8 is an oop
{method} 
 - klass: {other class}
EDI=0x01861c00 is a thread


Stack: [0x00500000,0x00550000],  sp=0x0054fc30,  free space=319k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  0x0054fc83

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.test.jni.TestJNI.wrapOpenSession5(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I+0
j  com.test.jni.Test.wrapOpenSession5(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)I+2
j  com.test.jni.Example.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+773
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x018de000 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_new, id=1208, stack(0x00000000,0x00000000)]
  0x018cec00 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2412, stack(0x03c80000,0x03cd0000)]
  0x018cdc00 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1824, stack(0x03c30000,0x03c80000)]
  0x018ccc00 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1848, stack(0x03be0000,0x03c30000)]
  0x018c7000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3224, stack(0x03b90000,0x03be0000)]
  0x018c2400 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3404, stack(0x03b40000,0x03b90000)]
=>0x01861c00 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=3428, stack(0x00500000,0x00550000)]

Other Threads:
  0x01885c00 VMThread [stack: 0x03af0000,0x03b40000] [id=2320]
  0x018f8c00 WatcherThread [stack: 0x03d20000,0x03d70000] [id=1380]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 482K [0x238b0000, 0x23e00000, 0x28e00000)
  eden space 4416K,  10% used [0x238b0000, 0x23928a30, 0x23d00000)
  from space 512K,   0% used [0x23d00000, 0x23d00000, 0x23d80000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x23d80000, 0x23d80000, 0x23e00000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 0K [0x28e00000, 0x298b0000, 0x338b0000)
   the space 10944K,   0% used [0x28e00000, 0x28e00000, 0x28e00200, 0x298b0000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 146K [0x338b0000, 0x344b0000, 0x378b0000)
   the space 12288K,   1% used [0x338b0000, 0x338d4be0, 0x338d4c00, 0x344b0000)
    ro space 10240K,  51% used [0x378b0000, 0x37ddda30, 0x37dddc00, 0x382b0000)
    rw space 12288K,  55% used [0x382b0000, 0x38949b50, 0x38949c00, 0x38eb0000)

Code Cache  [0x01960000, 0x019d0000, 0x03960000)
 total_blobs=134 nmethods=3 adapters=68 free_code_cache=33104512 largest_free_block=0

Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x00425000     C:\Windows\system32\java.exe
0x77b80000 - 0x77cbd000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x77950000 - 0x77a24000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x75d50000 - 0x75d9a000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x77a30000 - 0x77ad0000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x77ad0000 - 0x77b7c000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x76fb0000 - 0x76fc9000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x77d00000 - 0x77da1000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x7c340000 - 0x7c396000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\msvcr71.dll
0x6d7f0000 - 0x6da9f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x77790000 - 0x77859000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x76e90000 - 0x76ede000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x77120000 - 0x7712a000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x76c30000 - 0x76ccd000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x743d0000 - 0x74402000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x77cc0000 - 0x77cdf000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x77130000 - 0x771fc000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x75bd0000 - 0x75c1b000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x6d7a0000 - 0x6d7ac000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\verify.dll
0x6d320000 - 0x6d33f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.dll
0x6d7e0000 - 0x6d7ef000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\zip.dll
0x67140000 - 0x67224000     C:\jni\lib\CiscoEnergyWiseJni.dll
0x6cc80000 - 0x6cee7000     c:\jni\lib\CiscoEnergyWiseApi.dll
0x10000000 - 0x10113000     c:\jni\lib\libeay32.dll
0x76ee0000 - 0x76f15000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x76c20000 - 0x76c26000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x68430000 - 0x684d3000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4926_none_508ed732bcbc0e5a\MSVCR90.dll
0x77cf0000 - 0x77cf5000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL

VM Arguments:
java_command: CiscoEnergyWiseJni.jar -h 2.2.2.18 -l 10.211.55.3 -d colin -s lab
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\swig\swigwin-2.0.4;C:\cygwin\jdk1.6.0_30\bin;C:\cygwin;c:\jni\lib
USERNAME=cgswtsu78
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 37 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 Build 7600 

CPU:total 1 (1 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 37 stepping 5, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt

Memory: 4k page, physical 1048120k(542096k free), swap 2096696k(1160996k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.5-b03) for windows-x86 JRE (1.6.0_30-b12), built on Nov 10 2011 01:51:00 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 7.1 (VS2003)

time: Sun Jan 08 21:29:01 2012
elapsed time: 0 seconds
```

**Crash Report with -Xcheck:jni:**

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x6d896d32, pid=3552, tid=3264
#
# JRE version: 6.0_30-b12
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.5-b03 mixed mode, sharing windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# V  [jvm.dll+0xa6d32]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x01921c00):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=3264, stack(0x00170000,0x001c0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, reading address 0x0000001d

Registers:
EAX=0x00000021, EBX=0x001bfc48, ECX=0x382b0998, EDX=0x00000004
ESP=0x001bfbc0, EBP=0x001bfbcc, ESI=0x01921c00, EDI=0x0000001d
EIP=0x6d896d32, EFLAGS=0x00210206

Top of Stack: (sp=0x001bfbc0)
0x001bfbc0:   338d3c98 01921c00 338d3c98 001bfbe8
0x001bfbd0:   67145e4b 01921d28 001bfc48 00000021
0x001bfbe0:   0000000b 00000001 001bfc30 01a29fb7
0x001bfbf0:   01921d28 001bfc38 0000000b 001bfc4c
0x001bfc00:   001bfc48 00000016 00000021 01921c00
0x001bfc10:   001bfc10 338d3c98 001bfc50 338d48b8
0x001bfc20:   00000000 338d3c98 00000000 001bfc40
0x001bfc30:   001bfc74 01a22f45 338d4858 01a282d9 

Instructions: (pc=0x6d896d32)
0x6d896d12:   f5 ff 8b 45 10 83 c4 0c 85 c0 75 11 8b 15 a0 f2
0x6d896d22:   a6 6d 50 53 57 ff 92 a8 02 00 00 eb 2a 8d 78 fc
0x6d896d32:   81 3f 12 48 12 48 74 0d 68 18 80 a1 6d e8 fc bd
0x6d896d42:   ff ff 83 c4 04 8b 45 08 8b 0d a0 f2 a6 6d 57 53 


Register to memory mapping:

EAX=0x00000021 is an unknown value
EBX=0x001bfc48 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x01921c00
ECX=0x382b0998 is an oop
{instance class} 
 - klass: {other class}
EDX=0x00000004 is an unknown value
ESP=0x001bfbc0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x01921c00
EBP=0x001bfbcc is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x01921c00
ESI=0x01921c00 is a thread
EDI=0x0000001d is an unknown value


Stack: [0x00170000,0x001c0000],  sp=0x001bfbc0,  free space=318k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [jvm.dll+0xa6d32]
C  [EWJni.dll+0x5e4b]  Java_com_test_ewapi_jni_SampleJNI_sample_1wrapOpenSession1+0x133
j  com.test.ewapi.jni.SampleJNI.energywise_wrapOpenSession1(ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;II)I+0
j  com.test.ewapi.jni.Sample.wrapOpenSession1(ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;II)I+6
j  com.test.ewapi.jni.Example.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+667
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0xfac3b]
V  [jvm.dll+0x18c3a1]
V  [jvm.dll+0xfacbd]
V  [jvm.dll+0x95776]
V  [jvm.dll+0x9d6b8]
V  [jvm.dll+0xaf16b]
C  [java.exe+0x2155]
C  [java.exe+0x85b4]
C  [kernel32.dll+0x51114]  BaseThreadInitThunk+0x12
C  [ntdll.dll+0x5b429]  RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x63
C  [ntdll.dll+0x5b3fc]  RtlInitializeExceptionChain+0x36

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  com.test.ewapi.jni.SampleJNI.energywise_wrapOpenSession1(ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;II)I+0
j  com.test.ewapi.jni.Sample.wrapOpenSession1(ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;II)I+6
j  com.test.ewapi.jni.Example.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+667
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0199f400 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=140, stack(0x03d10000,0x03d60000)]
  0x0198fc00 JavaThread "C1 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=432, stack(0x03cc0000,0x03d10000)]
  0x0198ec00 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3520, stack(0x03c70000,0x03cc0000)]
  0x0198e000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2868, stack(0x03c20000,0x03c70000)]
  0x01987000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2340, stack(0x03bd0000,0x03c20000)]
  0x01982400 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2684, stack(0x03b80000,0x03bd0000)]
=>0x01921c00 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=3264, stack(0x00170000,0x001c0000)]

Other Threads:
  0x01946000 VMThread [stack: 0x03b30000,0x03b80000] [id=1420]
  0x019b9c00 WatcherThread [stack: 0x03d60000,0x03db0000] [id=2336]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 4928K, used 482K [0x238b0000, 0x23e00000, 0x28e00000)
  eden space 4416K,  10% used [0x238b0000, 0x23928a30, 0x23d00000)
  from space 512K,   0% used [0x23d00000, 0x23d00000, 0x23d80000)
  to   space 512K,   0% used [0x23d80000, 0x23d80000, 0x23e00000)
 tenured generation   total 10944K, used 0K [0x28e00000, 0x298b0000, 0x338b0000)
   the space 10944K,   0% used [0x28e00000, 0x28e00000, 0x28e00200, 0x298b0000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 146K [0x338b0000, 0x344b0000, 0x378b0000)
   the space 12288K,   1% used [0x338b0000, 0x338d4aa0, 0x338d4c00, 0x344b0000)
    ro space 10240K,  51% used [0x378b0000, 0x37ddda30, 0x37dddc00, 0x382b0000)
    rw space 12288K,  55% used [0x382b0000, 0x38949b50, 0x38949c00, 0x38eb0000)

Code Cache  [0x01a20000, 0x01a90000, 0x03a20000)
 total_blobs=126 nmethods=3 adapters=68 free_code_cache=33106048 largest_free_block=0

Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x00425000     C:\Windows\system32\java.exe
0x77b80000 - 0x77cbd000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x77950000 - 0x77a24000     C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll
0x75d50000 - 0x75d9a000     C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x77a30000 - 0x77ad0000     C:\Windows\system32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x77ad0000 - 0x77b7c000     C:\Windows\system32\msvcrt.dll
0x76fb0000 - 0x76fc9000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\sechost.dll
0x77d00000 - 0x77da1000     C:\Windows\system32\RPCRT4.dll
0x7c340000 - 0x7c396000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\msvcr71.dll
0x6d7f0000 - 0x6da9f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x77790000 - 0x77859000     C:\Windows\system32\USER32.dll
0x76e90000 - 0x76ede000     C:\Windows\system32\GDI32.dll
0x77120000 - 0x7712a000     C:\Windows\system32\LPK.dll
0x76c30000 - 0x76ccd000     C:\Windows\system32\USP10.dll
0x743d0000 - 0x74402000     C:\Windows\system32\WINMM.dll
0x77cc0000 - 0x77cdf000     C:\Windows\system32\IMM32.DLL
0x77130000 - 0x771fc000     C:\Windows\system32\MSCTF.dll
0x75bd0000 - 0x75c1b000     C:\Windows\system32\apphelp.dll
0x6d7a0000 - 0x6d7ac000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\verify.dll
0x6d320000 - 0x6d33f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\java.dll
0x6d7e0000 - 0x6d7ef000     C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\zip.dll
0x67140000 - 0x67224000     C:\jni\lib\EWJni.dll
0x6cc80000 - 0x6cee7000     c:\jni\lib\EWCApi.dll
0x10000000 - 0x10113000     c:\jni\lib\libeay32.dll
0x76ee0000 - 0x76f15000     C:\Windows\system32\WS2_32.dll
0x76c20000 - 0x76c26000     C:\Windows\system32\NSI.dll
0x6c050000 - 0x6c0f3000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.vc90.crt_1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b_9.0.30729.4926_none_508ed732bcbc0e5a\MSVCR90.dll
0x77cf0000 - 0x77cf5000     C:\Windows\system32\PSAPI.DLL

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Xcheck:jni 
java_command: EWJni.jar -h 2.2.2.18 -l 10.211.55.3 -d coling -s lab
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\swig\swigwin-2.0.4;C:\cygwin\jdk1.6.0_30\bin;C:\cygwin;c:\jni\lib
USERNAME=cgswtsu78
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=x86 Family 6 Model 37 Stepping 5, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 7 Build 7600 

CPU:total 1 (1 cores per cpu, 1 threads per core) family 6 model 37 stepping 5, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt

Memory: 4k page, physical 1048120k(610804k free), swap 2096696k(1308820k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (20.5-b03) for windows-x86 JRE (1.6.0_30-b12), built on Nov 10 2011 01:51:00 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 7.1 (VS2003)

time: Mon Jan 09 10:29:45 2012
elapsed time: 0 seconds
```

**SWIG Compilation Output:**

```
 [exec] mkdir -p obj
 [exec] swig -java -I/test/java/jdk-1.6.0_30/include/linux -I/test/jni/include -I/test/java/jdk-1.6.0_30/include  -package com.test.ewapi.jni -outdir ../src/java/com/test/ewapi/jni ewapi.i
 [exec] /test/mingw/mingw32/bin/i386-mingw32-gcc  -Wall -fpic -I/test/java/jdk-1.6.0_30/include/linux -I/test/jni/include -I/test/java/jdk-1.6.0_30/include  -O0 -g3 -fno-strict-aliasing -c ewapi_wrap.c -o obj/ewapi_wrap.o
 [exec] ewapi_wrap.c:1: warning: -fpic ignored for target (all code is position independent)
 [exec] /test/mingw/mingw32/bin/i386-mingw32-gcc  obj/ewapi_wrap.o -shared -L/test/jni/lib -lEWApi -lm -leay32 -lws2_32 -lrpcrt4 -o /test/jni/lib/SampleJni.dll
 [exec] rm ewapi_wrap.c
```

**Error when running Java main with Xcheck:jni JVM option:**

```
FATAL ERROR in native method: ReleaseStringUTFChars called on something not allo
cated by GetStringUTFChars at com.test.ewapi.jni.SampleJNI.wrapOpenSession1
(Native Method) at com.test.ewapi.jni.Sample.wrapOpenSession1(Unknown So
urce) at com.test.ewapi.jni.Example.main(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Can you show us your code which implements the code generated by javah? If you are not implementing the bridging code to call the code above correctly, it can corrupt the stack or heap.

Comment: @PeterLawrey - I've added the SWIG generated JNI files.  There are other methods in these files but I'm only calling wrapSession1 and wrapSession5 from my Java main test class.

Comment: I would check if its having a problem converting the `String` to `char *` Can you try a method with no parameters and one with just `int` parameter? BTW: JNI and SWIG are quite different in implementation. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey - I did try what you mentioned and the crash will not occur when the method has 0 params, has all ints, one char* pointer.  It will crash when a function has two or more char* parameters, with one exception.  If I have more int parameters than char* parameters then its fine. Its very weird.  The same code works on Linux, but of course the libraries are built differently.

Comment: the char* to String conversion is automatically handled by SWIG..supposedly..

Comment: Quite a bit of magic has to happen to convert a `String` into a `char *` so that is why I suspected this could be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is the problem discussed [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8145605/swig-v1-3-29-generated-c-to-java-vector-class-not-acting-properly)

tl;dr:

You absolutely, positively *must* use `-fno-strict-aliasing` if you're compiling SWIG-generated code with a recent version of `g++`. Not doing so will result in hard-to-diagnose hard crashes which have precisely this "random, but consistent" behavior.

Comment: I added the -fno-strict-aliasing to the CFLAGS section of my makefile.  I detailed the response I get in my original question, any ideas on what is going on here?

Comment: Is there any chance there's a buffer-overrun error in any of the native APIs you're wrapping? Something may be smashing the stack for you.

Comment: would that have a chance of happening even if I'm only calling one api?  What's the best way to figure this out? There error does happen when I have more char* parameters than ints.  If I have 4 char* and 4 5 int params the function works.  4 char* and 4 ints it wont work.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently the C code dereferences `NULL` somewhere:

```
EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x0054fc83, pid=912, tid=3428
```

The `0xc0000005` index suggests accessing 5th index of `NULL` pointer:

```
char* c = NULL;
//...
c[5] = 4  //fail
```

Comment: I added the C functions referenced in the crash logs and they both just retun an int and don't have any logic.  Can you make any sense of that?

Comment: `0xc0000005` is the exception code to indicate it is an access violation.  Also, note the 'c' in the begining of the hex number, not the 5th element.