# SWIG and shared_ptr: javaout typemap not applied to map template

Tags: java, android, opencv, swig

### The Problem

I'm working on an Android application in which I have to pass a OpenCV Mat between the Java code an the C++ code. For this purpose I created the following SWIG typemaps which are working fine:

```
%include "std_map.i"
%include "std_shared_ptr.i"
...
%shared_ptr(cv::Mat)
...
// normal typemaps for cv::Mat w/o shared_ptr
%typemap(jstype) cv::Mat, cv::Mat& "org.opencv.core.Mat"
%typemap(javain) cv::Mat, cv::Mat& "$javainput.getNativeObjAddr()"
%typemap(jtype) cv::Mat, cv::Mat& "long"
%typemap(jni) cv::Mat, cv::Mat& "jlong" 

%typemap(in) cv::Mat, cv::Mat& {
    $1 = *(cv::Mat **)&$input;
}
%typemap(javaout) cv::Mat, cv::Mat& {
    return new org.opencv.core.Mat($jnicall);
}

// rather hacky javaout typemap override for the shared_ptr
%typemap(javaout) std::shared_ptr< cv::Mat > {
    long cPtr = $jnicall;
    return (cPtr == 0) ? null : new org.opencv.core.Mat(cPtr);
}
```

Anyhow, at some point I have to return a `std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<cv::Mat>>` to Java. I did this using the map template with

```
%template(Map_String_Shared_ptr_Mat) std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<cv::Mat>>;
```

which produces the following `get`method in Java:

```
public org.opencv.core.Mat get(String key) {
    long cPtr = xyJNI.Map_String_Shared_ptr_Mat_get(swigCPtr, this, key);
    return (cPtr == 0) ? null : new org.opencv.core.Mat(cPtr, true);
```

}

which is not using the javaout typemap provided earlier. *(It works on a function returning a `std::shared_ptr<cv::Mat>` but not in the map template)*

### What I've tried so far

I tried to insert my own `get` method via

```
%typemap(javacode) std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<cv::Mat>> %{
   public org.opencv.Mat get{
      ...
   }
%};
```

but this results in a conflict since two get methods exist.

Also, when I tried to `%ignore` the `get` method first, the corresponding `xyJNI.Map_String_Shared_ptr_Mat_get(swigCPtr, this, key);` is not created, and therefor I can't provide my own implementation of the `get`

### The Question

Now I need either a way to tell SWIG to apply that javaout typemap. But I would also be fine with a way of overriding the `get` method body, to use the correct constructor for a Mat.

I hope someone can help me with this issue

*Note: I don't care about `Map_String_Shared_ptr_Mat` not being a real `Map` in Java. That's not a problem for me*

**Edit:**
Added the shared_ptr javaout typemap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I was not able to find a solution to either have the `javaout` typemap applied to the `Mat_String_Shared_ptr_Mat.get()`, nor to substitute the method content of `Mat_String_Shared_ptr_Mat.get()`.

What I ended up with is a workaround which returns the referenced `cv::Mat` (so not the `shared_ptr`) in a `getPlain()` method, to which the typemap is applied.

This is certainly not the perfect solution I was looking for, but it might help others facing a similar problem.

---

### Solution

```
%include "std_map.i"

// 1.
%typemap(javaout) cv::Mat, cv::Mat& {
    return new org.opencv.core.Mat($jnicall);
}

...

// 2.
%ignore std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<cv::Mat>>::get;

// 3.
%template(Map_String_Shared_ptr_Mat) std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<cv::Mat>>;

// 4.
%extend std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<cv::Mat>>{
    const cv::Mat& getPlain(const std::string& key) throw (std::out_of_range) {
        std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr< cv::Mat > >::iterator i = self->find(key);
        if (i != self->end())
            return *i->second;
        else
            throw std::out_of_range("key not found");
    }
}
```

1. The typemap for the cv::Mat which is (unlike the shared_ptr typemap) applied to the wrapped map
2. Ignore the `get` function (which will be self-implemented in step 4)
3. Have SWIG create the wrapper via the template defined in `std_map.i`
4. Extend the wrapper by adding a `getPlain` function to the map. This function returns the referenced `cv::Mat` object itself, rather than the `shared_ptr`. The `javaout` typemap of step 1 is applied when creating the Java code

---

### Output

After running SWIG, the Java class `Map_String_Shared_ptr_Mat` contains the required `getPlain` method:

```
public org.opencv.core.Mat getPlain(String key) {
     return new org.opencv.core.Mat(xyJNI.Map_String_Shared_ptr_Mat_getPlain(swigCPtr, this, key));
}
```

---

### Update

*Note: This part is specific to cv::Mat*

Because of the implementation of cv::Mat in Java, I had to change the implementation to perform call by reference in C++.

This is because the Java Mat implementation stores a pointer to the C++ Mat. In the `finalize` method, the C++ object is freed. In the previous implementation, the object may have been deleted already, which would result in a SIGSEGV crash.

Therefore the implementation was changed to the following:

```
%extend std::map<std::string, std::shared_ptr<cv::Mat>>{
    void getPlain(const std::string& key, cv::Mat& dest) throw (std::out_of_range) {
        std::map<std::string,std::shared_ptr< cv::Mat > >::iterator i = self->find(key);
        if (i != self->end()){
             (*i->second).copyTo(dest);
        } else{
            throw std::out_of_range("key not found");
        }
    }
```

which copies the data to the Mat in the second parameters, which itself is created in Java (and thus does not produce seg faults wenn freed).

---

The solution can be adjusted to create/wrap implementations for `set`and other functions respectively.

*Note: I also ended up using some of the methods presented in this post: [Passing Java Map<String, String> to C++ method using SWIG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10812607/passing-java-mapstring-string-to-c-method-using-swig/10828655#10828655), which is definitely worth to have a look at.*