# How would you create a typemap for std::list<std::string> to List<String> in C++ to Java in SWIG?

Tags: java, c++, swig

In SWIG 3.0.8 there is no implementation for `std::list` in the C++ to Java map, only `std::vector`. This isn't very ideal for most cases, so I was wondering if it is possible to create my own SWIG definition of `std::list` and how would I do so?

Comment: Short answer: you probably don't want to map it to `List<String>` anyway, implementing `AbstractList` is a much better idea. I've written a few answers on similar subjects before, see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12551108/168175 http://stackoverflow.com/a/8190135/168175

Comment: (Forgot to add: [`AbstractSequentialList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSequentialList.html) is a better base class for `std::list`). Happy to write up an equivalent answer here if you want though.

Comment: @Flexo My base C++ object uses `std::list`, I am abit confused as to how your previous answers help me? Would greatly appreciate if you write it up!

Answer (score 1):

I've written a set of typemaps that should just work for wrapping `std::list` nicely in Java. They use [`java.util.AbstractSequentialList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractSequentialList.html) as a base class, so there's only ever one copy of data in existence and it works nicely as both a Java and C++ data structure. This answer is broadly an improvement and port of the same techniques I used in [an older answer wrapping `std::vector`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12551108/168175) similarly.

Firstly I pulled the 'autobox' typemap out of my older answer and into a standalone file, autobox.i since I'm now reusing it quite a lot:

```
// Java typemaps for autoboxing in return types of generics
%define AUTOBOX(CTYPE, JTYPE)
%typemap(autobox) CTYPE, const CTYPE&, CTYPE& "JTYPE"
%enddef
AUTOBOX(double, Double)
AUTOBOX(float, Float)
AUTOBOX(boolean, Boolean)
AUTOBOX(signed char, Byte)
AUTOBOX(short, Short)
AUTOBOX(int, Integer)
AUTOBOX(long, Long)
AUTOBOX(SWIGTYPE, $typemap(jstype,$1_basetype))
```

Then I used this in my std_list.i file below:

```
%include <autobox.i>
%include <stdint.i>

%{
#include <list>
#include <algorithm>
%}

namespace std {
  template <typename T> class list {
  public:
    // This typedef is a weird hack to make stuff work
    typedef std::list<T>::iterator iterator;
    typedef size_t size_type;
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef T& reference;

    void assign(size_type n, const value_type &val);

    bool empty() const;

    list(size_type n, const value_type &value=value_type());
    list(const list &o);
    list();
    ~list();

    size_type max_size () const;

    void pop_back();
    void pop_front();
    void push_back(const value_type &x);
    void push_front(const value_type &x);
    void remove(const T &v);

    // Possible bug: jint != size_type
    jint size () const;
    void sort();

%javamethodmodifiers "private";
    // Only for helping implement listIterator
    iterator begin();
    iterator insert(iterator pos, const value_type &v);

    %extend {
      static void set(iterator pos, const value_type& v) {
        *pos = v;
      }

      jint previous_index(const iterator& pos) const {
        return pos == self->begin() ? -1 : std::distance(self->begin(), static_cast<std::list<T>::const_iterator>(pos));
      }

      jint next_index(const iterator& pos) const {
        return pos == self->end() ? self->size() : std::distance(self->begin(), static_cast<std::list<T>::const_iterator>(pos));
      }

      static iterator next(iterator pos) {
        return ++pos;
      }

      static iterator previous(iterator pos) {
        return --pos;
      }

      static value_type deref(const iterator& pos) {
        return *pos;
      }

      static void advance(iterator& pos, jint index) {
        std::advance(pos, index);
      }

      bool has_next(const iterator& pos) const {
        return pos != $self->end();
      }
    }
%javamethodmodifiers "public";
  };
}

%typemap(javaimports) std::list %{
  import java.util.AbstractSequentialList;
  import java.util.ListIterator;
  import java.util.NoSuchElementException;
  import java.util.Collection;
%}

%typemap(javabase) std::list "AbstractSequentialList<$typemap(autobox,$1_basetype::value_type)>"

#define JAVA_VALUE_TYPE $typemap(autobox,$1_basetype::value_type)
#define JAVA_ITERATOR_TYPE $typemap(jstype, $1_basetype::iterator)

%typemap(javacode,noblock=1) std::list {
  public $javaclassname(Collection c) {
    this();
    ListIterator<JAVA_VALUE_TYPE> it = listIterator(0);
    for (Object o: c) {
      it.add((JAVA_VALUE_TYPE)o);
    }
  }

  public ListIterator<JAVA_VALUE_TYPE> listIterator(int index) {
    return new ListIterator<JAVA_VALUE_TYPE>() {
      private JAVA_ITERATOR_TYPE pos;
      private JAVA_ITERATOR_TYPE last;

      private ListIterator<JAVA_VALUE_TYPE> init(int index) {
        pos = $javaclassname.this.begin();
        $javaclassname.advance(pos, index);
        return this;
      }

      public void add(JAVA_VALUE_TYPE v) {
        // Technically we can invalidate last here, but this makes more sense
        last=$javaclassname.this.insert(pos, v);
      }

      public void set(JAVA_VALUE_TYPE v) {
        if (null==last) {
          throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        $javaclassname.set(last, v);
      }

      public void remove() {
        if (null==last) {
          throw new IllegalStateException();
        }
        $javaclassname.this.remove(last);
        last=null;
      }

      public int previousIndex() {
        return $javaclassname.this.previous_index(pos);
      }

      public int nextIndex() {
        return $javaclassname.this.next_index(pos);
      }

      public JAVA_VALUE_TYPE previous() {
        if (previousIndex() < 0) {
          throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        last = pos;
        pos = $javaclassname.previous(pos);
        return $javaclassname.deref(last);
      }

      public JAVA_VALUE_TYPE next() {
        if (!hasNext()) {
          throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        last = pos;
        pos = $javaclassname.next(pos);  
        return $javaclassname.deref(last);
      }

      public boolean hasPrevious() {
        return previousIndex() != -1;
      }

      public boolean hasNext() { 
        return $javaclassname.this.has_next(pos);
      }
    }.init(index);
  }
}
```

This file implements `AbstractSequentialList`, which mostly just boils down to implementing [`ListIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html). That's somewhat fiddly because the way Java implements the concept of an iterator is somewhat different to the C++ abstraction, although not completely different.

Our Java implementation of `ListIterator` is mostly just a wrapper around an opaque C++ iterator and some glue to call in to a little extra C++ code that actually uses `std::advance`, `std::distance` and `operator++`/`operator--` to meet the requirements needed. Inside the glue are the various checks needed to make the interface safe/robust as a Java programmer expects.

The SWIG interface to std::list consists of the following major parts:

1. Declaration of the relevant parts of `std::list` itself. (Some is private because it makes no sense to Java as anything other than an implementation detail)
2. Some extra private code to let us instantiate some of the templated C++ iterator code we need when we use `%template` inside SWIG later on.
3. Setting up imports/baseclass for `std::list`
4. Some helper macros to make it easier to write 'the type that Java knows an opaque handle to a C++ iterator as' and 'the type that Java thinks our container holds, including any autoboxing if needed' as they get written a lot.
5. Some additional Java code for every `std::list<X>` we wrap:

   1. Another constructor as recommended by Java collections interface for copying from one collection to another. (This one uses the Java iterator we created to do it fairly efficiently).
   2. An implementation of `listIterator` abstract method that returns an anonymous type that glues everything together to meet all of the requirements for a mutable `ListIterator`.

   This is wrapped inside `{ }` with noblock turned on so that the preprocessor macros happen, but that `{ }` doesn't get inserted into the Java which is generated.

   I also used this [Java trick to pass data to an anonymous class during construction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12206542/168175) (but could have used [the double brace magic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1005083/168175) instead).

With that in place we can validate it by running writing a SWIG module, test.i:

```
%module test

%include "std_list.i"
%include <std_string.i>

%template(DoubleList) std::list<double>;
%template(StringList) std::list<std::string>;
```

And some actual Java to exercise it:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class run {
  public static void dump(java.util.AbstractCollection c) {
    for (Object o: c) {
      System.out.println(o);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] argv) {
    System.loadLibrary("test");
    for (int i = 0; i < 1; ++i) {
      go();
//      System.gc();
    }
  }

  public static void go() {
    StringList sl = new StringList();
    dump(sl);
    sl.add(0,"HELLO"); // 1 arg form also worked
    sl.add(1,"WORLD");
    sl.add(2,"testing");
    sl.add(3,"some more");
    System.out.println(sl.size());
    dump(sl);

    sl = new StringList(new ArrayList<String>() {{
      add("A");
      add("B");
      add("C");
    }});
    dump(sl);
  }
}
```

Which works as expected:

```
swig3.0 -java -c++ -Wall test.i 
javac *.java 
g++ -Wall -Wextra -shared -o libtest.so test_wrap.cxx -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/ -I/usr/lib/jvm/default-java/include/linux -fPIC  -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. java run
```

Gives:

```
4
HELLO
WORLD
testing
some more
A
B
C
```

A random note: `hasNext()` and forward iteration is probably faster than `hasPrevious()` and reverse iteration simply because it's easier to avoid the `std::distance` call int that case.

(Caveat: I read the Java docs on what the semantics of the ListIterator member functions should be in rather a hurry. I could have got one or more of them subtly wrong).