# How to convert (typemap) C++ vector of vectors to Java with SWIG

Tags: java, c++, swig

Could someone help me with the description of `SWIG typemap` for converting a jagged C++ vector of vectors of type `uint32_t` to an equivalent java jagged vector of longs?

This is what I have so far in my interface  file and I still end up needing pointer access on my java side.

Would appreciate descriptive code if possible.

Thank you for your time and help.

```
  %include "std_vector.i"
%{
  #define SWIG_JAVA_EXTRA_NATIVE_CONTAINERS 
%}
%typemap(out) uint32_t %{ $result = (jlong)$1; %}

// Instantiate vector templates used by SimpleR
namespace std {
   %template(IntVector)             vector<int>;
   %template(DoubleVector)          vector<double>;
   %template(LongVector)            vector<uint32_t>;
   %rename(LongVector)              vector<uint32_t>;
   %template(LongVectorVector)      vector<vector<uint32_t> >;
   %template(BooleanVector)         vector<bool>;
   %template(StringVector)          vector<string>;
   %template(ConstCharVector)       vector<const char*>;
   %template(RepresentationVector)  vector<SimpleR::ModelRepresentation *>;
}

// In pop()
%typemap(out) std::vector<std::vector<uint32_t> >::value_type { 
$result = SWIG_NewPointerObj(SWIG_as_voidptr(&$1), $descriptor(std::vector<uint32_t>), 0 |  0 ); 
} 

// In front(), back(), __getitem__()
%typemap(out) std::vector<std::vector<uint32_t> >::value_type & { 
    $result = SWIG_NewPointerObj(SWIG_as_voidptr($1), $descriptor(std::vector<uint32_t>), 0 |  0 ); 
}
```

Comment: Something like: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12551108/168175 or http://stackoverflow.com/a/8190135/168175 perhaps?