# Convert Current date to integer

Tags: java, date

I want to convert the current date to integer value. By default, it returns long. When I try to convert long to integer, and afterwards I convert the integer value to date, means it shows 1970's date,

```
 int i = (int) new Date().getTime();
 System.out.println("Integer : " + i);
 System.out.println("Long : "+ new Date().getTime());
 System.out.println("Long date : " + new Date(new Date().getTime()));
 System.out.println("Int Date : " + new Date(i));
```

the output as follows:

```
Integer : 1292838124
Long : 1345617601771
Long date : Wed Aug 22 12:10:01 IST 2012
Int Date : Fri Jan 16 04:37:18 IST 1970
```

Any one please help me out, how to convert current date to integer(10 digit number)?

Comment: o/p is : Integer : 1293630553,
Long : 1345618394201,
Long date : Wed Aug 22 12:23:14 IST 2012,
Int Date : Fri Jan 16 04:50:30 IST 1970

Comment: I think you gave wrong output in question

Comment: Sorry for my mistake.. Now i change it

Comment: Is the integer required because a jdbc operation is using preparedStatement.setInt(aInt)?

Comment: Related: [Safely casting long to int in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590831/safely-casting-long-to-int-in-java)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

The issue is that an Integer is not large enough to store a current date, you need to use a Long.

The date is stored internally as the number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970.

The maximum Integer value is 2147483648, whereas the number of milliseconds since 1970 is currently in the order of 1345618537869

Putting the maximum integer value into a date yields Monday 26th January 1970.

Edit: Code to display division by 1000 as per comment below:

```
    int i = (int) (new Date().getTime()/1000);
    System.out.println("Integer : " + i);
    System.out.println("Long : "+ new Date().getTime());
    System.out.println("Long date : " + new Date(new Date().getTime()));
    System.out.println("Int Date : " + new Date(((long)i)*1000L));

Integer : 1345619256
Long : 1345619256308
Long date : Wed Aug 22 16:37:36 CST 2012
Int Date : Wed Aug 22 16:37:36 CST 2012
```

Comment: Thank you shonky, I accept your answer. But my requirement is to maintain only integer not long.. Is there any other way to achieve my requirement.

Comment: If you're willing to live with a resolution of one second (you would lose the milliseconds component of the date) then you could divide by 1000 prior to storing the integer. And multiply to convert back.  However it would have a limited life (a sort of Y2K issue) - up to 2038.

Comment: I have added code to my answer to demonstrate the suggestion above

Comment: FYI, counting whole seconds since beginning of 1970 UTC while ignoring leap seconds is known as [Unix Time](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Answer (score 13):

In order to get current date as integer(10 digit number), you need to divide the long returned from new Date().getTime() by 1000.

This will be in int range and is good until 18 Jan 2038.

Answer (score 10):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.now().getEpochSecond()  // The number of seconds from the Java epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.
```

## Details

As others stated, a [32-bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/32-bit) integer cannot hold a number big enough for the number of seconds from the epoch (beginning of 1970 in UTC) and now. You need [64-bit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit) integer (a `long` primitive or [`Long`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html) object).

## java.time

The other answers are using old legacy date-time classes. They have been supplanted by the java.time classes.

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond).

```
Instant now = instant.now() ;
```

You can interrogate for the number of milliseconds since the epoch. Beware this means a loss of data, truncating nanoseconds to milliseconds.

```
long millisecondsSinceEpoch = now.toEpochMilli() ;
```

If you want a count of nanoseconds since epoch, you will need to do a bit of math as the class oddly lacks a `toEpochNano` method. Note the `L` appended to the billion to provoke the calculation as 64-bit long integers.

```
long nanosecondsSinceEpoch = ( instant.getEpochSecond() * 1_000_000_000L ) + instant.getNano() ;
```

## Whole seconds since epoch

But the end of the Question asks for a 10-digit number. I suspect that means a count of *whole* seconds since the epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00. This is commonly referred to as [Unix Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) or Posix Time.

We can interrogate the `Instant` for this number. Again, this means a loss of data with the truncation of any fraction-of-second this object may hold.

```
long secondsSinceEpoch = now.getEpochSecond() ;  // The number of seconds from the Java epoch of 1970-01-01T00:00:00Z.
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), [**Java SE 11**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_11), and later  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.

  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Most of the *java.time* functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the *java.time* classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 7):

If you need only an integer representing elapsed days since Jan. 1, 1970, you can try these:

```
// magic number=
// millisec * sec * min * hours
// 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 = 86400000
public static final long MAGIC=86400000L;

public int DateToDays (Date date){
    //  convert a date to an integer and back again
    long currentTime=date.getTime();
    currentTime=currentTime/MAGIC;
    return (int) currentTime; 
}

public Date DaysToDate(int days) {
    //  convert integer back again to a date
    long currentTime=(long) days*MAGIC;
    return new Date(currentTime);
}
```

Shorter but less readable (slightly faster?):

```
public static final long MAGIC=86400000L;

public int DateToDays (Date date){
    return (int) (date.getTime()/MAGIC);
}

public Date DaysToDate(int days) {
    return new Date((long) days*MAGIC);
}
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT: This could work until Fri Jul 11 01:00:00 CET 5881580

Answer (score 4):

Do you need something like this(without time)?

```
public static Integer toJulianDate(Date pDate) {
if (pDate == null) {
  return null;
}
Calendar lCal = Calendar.getInstance();
lCal.setTime(pDate);
int lYear = lCal.get(Calendar.YEAR);
int lMonth = lCal.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
int lDay = lCal.get(Calendar.DATE);
int a = (14 - lMonth) / 12;
int y = lYear + 4800 - a;
int m = lMonth + 12 * a - 3;
return lDay + (153 * m + 2) / 5 + 365 * y + y / 4 - y / 100 + y / 400 - 32045;
}
```

Comment: @Stefan Thank you for the solution. But can u please explain whats happening here.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this as is shown below:

```
    long year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    long month = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1;
    long day = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    long calcDate = year * 100 + month;
    calcDate = calcDate * 100 + day;
    System.out.println("int: " + calcDate);
```

Comment: This question has already been solved, and since it's over 2 years old, there doesn't seem to be a reason to add another answer.

Comment: This Answer does not address the Question. The Question asked how to fit the number into an `int` rather than a `long`. The [correct accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12067775/642706) explains that is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
Calendar currentDay= Calendar.getInstance();
int currDate= currentDay.get(Calendar.DATE);
int currMonth= currentDay.get(Calendar.MONTH);
int currYear= currentDay.get(Calendar.YEAR);
System.out.println(currDate + "-" +  currMonth + "-" + currYear);
```

an alternative way using LocalDate.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
int currentDate= today.getDayOfMonth();
int currentMonth= today.getMonthValue();
int currentYear= today.getYear()
```

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. I’m afraid you misunderstood the question (or else I did). The asker wants to represent the current moment in time as *one* integer. Not three integers for day of month, month and year. Also the `Calendar` class is long outdated and poorly designed, not recommended anymore. And also we get 7 for month, where most would expect 8 in August.

Comment: maybe i misunderstood the  question. And regarding the Calendar class be deprecated, i just found that issue today and tried an alternative way using LocalDate.                                                                                                      
  LocalDate today = LocalDate.now();
  int currentDate= today.getDayOfMonth();
  int currentMonth= today.getMonthValue();
  int currentYear= today.getYear();

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem is because of [getTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime%28%29) . it always return following.

> Returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT represented by this Date object.

Because the max integer value is less then the return value by `getTime()` that why is showing 
wrong result.

Answer (score 0):

On my Java 7, the output is different:

```
Integer : 1293732698
Long : 1345618496346
Long date : Wed Aug 22 10:54:56 MSK 2012
Int Date : Fri Jan 16 02:22:12 MSK 1970
```

which is an expected behavior.

It is impossible to display the current date in milliseconds as an integer (10 digit number), because the latest possible date is `Sun Apr 26 20:46:39 MSK 1970`:

```
Date d = new Date(9999_9999_99L);
System.out.println("Date: " + d);

Date: Sun Apr 26 20:46:39 MSK 1970
```

You might want to consider displaying it in seconds/minutes.

Answer (score -1):

Simple really create a long variable that represents a default start date for your program
Get the date to another long variable.
Then deduct the long start date and convert to a integer voila
To read and convert back just add  rather than subtract.
obviously this is dependant on how large a date range you require.

Answer (score -1):

Java `Date` to `int` conversion:

```
public static final String DATE_FORMAT_INT = "yyyyMMdd";

public static String format(Date date, String format) {
    return isNull(date) ?  
    null : new SimpleDateFormat(format).format(date);
}

public static Integer getDateInt(Date date) {
    if (isNull(date)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Date must not be NULL");
    }

    return parseInt(format(date, DATE_FORMAT_INT));
}
```