# How to pass future time using "departure_time" as parameter into HTTP request via distance matrix api

Tags: java, android, httprequest, google-distancematrix-api

I am using [distant matrix api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start) to get the travel time between 2 points and I want to consider the traffics when calculating the travel time, I am calling the distance matrix while passing this URL as part of the request :

```
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&" +
                        "origins=" + startLat +"," + startlong  +
                        "&destinations=" + endLat +","+endLong +
                        //departure_time parameter
                        "&departure_time=now" +
                        "&key=my api key");
```

According to the documentation adding the departure_time parameter to my request will add the travel time data while considering traffics (in the URL above I am using the parameter as the request is sent).
I want to pass some time in the future as the departure_time parameter 
After reading the documentation it seems like I need to pass the time as int/long, (for example departure_time=1399995076).

Here is some time for example = 21:15 lets say on friday.

How can I convert this time or any time into int/long?

I have looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12067697/convert-current-date-as-integer) and many more related to the subject but none of them helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Departure time need the time in milliseconds, to get the current time in milliseconds you need to use `System.currentTimeMillis()`.
If you need time in the future add the numbers of hours in milliseconds, for example for 1 hour into the future is 3600000 milliseconds so use `System.currentTimeMillis() + 3600000`.

So in your code it will look like this:

```
Long future_time = System.currentTimeMillis() + 3600000;
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&" +
                        "origins=" + startLat +"," + startlong  +
                        "&destinations=" + endLat +","+endLong +
                        //departure_time parameter
                        "&departure_time=" + future_time +
                        "&key=my api key");
```