# How does long to int cast work in Java?

Tags: java, casting

This question is **not** about how a [long should be correctly cast to an int](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590831/safely-casting-long-to-int-in-java), but rather what happens when we incorrectly cast it to an int.

So consider this code -

```
   @Test
    public void longTest()
    {
        long longNumber = Long.MAX_VALUE;
        int intNumber = (int)longNumber; // potentially unsafe cast.
        System.out.println("longNumber = "+longNumber);
        System.out.println("intNumber = "+intNumber);
    }
```

This gives the output -

```
longNumber = 9223372036854775807
intNumber = -1
```

Now suppose I make the following change-

```
long longNumber = Long.MAX_VALUE - 50;
```

I then get the output -

```
longNumber = 9223372036854775757
intNumber = -51
```

The question is, **how** is the long's value being converted to an int?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The low 32 bits of the `long` are taken and put into the `int`.

Here's the math, though:

1. Treat negative `long` values as `2^64` plus that value.  So `-1` is treated as 2^64 - 1.  (This is the *unsigned* 64-bit value, and it's how the value is actually represented in binary.)
2. Take the result and mod by 2^32.  (This is the *unsigned* 32-bit value.)
3. If the result is >= 2^31, subtract 2^32.  (This is the signed 32-bit value, the Java `int`.)

Comment: +1 You can do `(l & 0xFFFFFFFFL) << 32 >> 32` to get the same value without a cast.

Comment: or you can just do `l << 32 >> 32` which will discard the top bits as well as do the sign extension.

Comment: Aaah, I knew that but I can't believe I had forgotten it when I asked the question! Thanks for the answer!