# Calling setProperty with int but getProperty returns Long on google app engine persistent storage

Tags: java, google-app-engine, entity

When using this code with DatastoreService I get ClassCastException Long acnnot be cast to integer in fromEntity. Is it normal behaviour? (I get this behaviour when debugging on local computer with google plugin for eclipse)

```
class UserData {
    private int _integerval = 0;
    private String _stringval = "";
    public Entity getEntity() {
        Entity ret = new Entity( "User", key );
        ret.setProperty( "property1", _integerval );
        ret.setProperty( "property2", _stringval );
        return ret;
    }

    public static UserData fromEntity( Entity ent ) {
        UserData ret = new UserData();
        ret._integerval = (Integer)ent.getProperty("property1");
        ret._stringval = (String)ent.getProperty("property2");
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Do I always have to catch this exception like this:

```
try
{
    ret._integerval = (Integer)ent.getProperty("property1");
}
catch( ClassCastException ex ) {
    Long val = (Long)ent.getProperty("property1");
    ret._integerval = val.intValue(); 
}
```

Or maybe all the numeric values are stored as long only? Do I have to change _integerval type to long to avoid this exceprion?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `int` instead of `Integer` while casting.

```
ret._integerval = (int)ent.getProperty("property1");
```

**Edit:**

The following is included in the [setProperty](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/PropertyContainer#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) API.

> As the value is stored in the datastore, it is converted to the
>   datastore's native type. This may include widening, such as converting
>   a Short to a Long.

So your *int* data is being converted to datastore's native type as `Long`. Cast using `long` or `Long`.

Comment: The same. Get java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer.

Answer (score 6):

Create a new Integer :

```
Integer property = new Integer(entity.getProperty("propertyKey").toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `int` in your programm then this works ok:

```
int i = (int) (long) entity.getProperty(propertyName);
```

Still be sure that the number gets into the int-range (discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590831/safely-casting-long-to-int-in-java)).

Answer (score 1):

As reported in the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/PropertyContainer#setProperty%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29)

> As the value is stored in the datastore, it is converted to the
>   datastore's native type. This may include widening, such as converting
>   a Short to a Long.

So

- Set as int but cast it to long because for some reason the datastore behaviour in local environment is different and it stores integer also.
- Get the Long and use .intValue()

  ```
  public int get() {
      return ((Long) entity.getProperty(FIELD)).intValue(); 
  }

  public void set(int value) {
      entity.setProperty(FIELD, (long)value); 
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Integer values are saved as Long, so app engine will always return Long, i was confused myself but then i saw [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses#IntegerProperty)