# Simpler method to autobox / cast a Long to int in java

Tags: java, casting

I've the following code in Java:

```
void foo(int a) { ... }

void bar() {
    Long x = 42;
    foo(x);  // Compile error: "Method foo(int)   
             // is not applicable for the argument (long)"
    foo((long) x); // Same as before
    foo((int) x); // Compile error: "Cannot cast Long to int"
    foo((int) (long) x);  // OK, but strange and confusing
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Try `foo(x.intValue())`. Also, `Long x = 42;` won't compile.

Comment: use an `int` for `x`, you are boxing `x` for nothing...

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590831/safely-casting-long-to-int-in-java?rq=1

Comment: @RC. In real-life I do not control `x` and `foo()` -- that's the point of my question: I have to somehow down-cast.

Comment: then @rgettman answer is the way, IMHO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a `Long` object, you can call the [`intValue()` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Long.html#intValue%28%29) to get an `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your x as a long, not a Long, and you will be able to cast directly to (int)