# Java zipfile/byte array issue

Tags: java, arrays, byte, primitive, zip

I have a zip file with 3 relatively large (several mb) binary files I need to read into a buffer to perform some regex operations on.

```
//For entry in zip.getentries loop above

long size = entry.getSize();

byte[] bytes = new byte[(int) size];

int numBytesRead = zipFile.getInputStream(entry).read(bytes);

if (numBytesRead != size) {
     Logger.getLogger(this.getClass()).debug(
                "Read " + numBytesRead + " bytes from zip entry but size of the  
                zip entry is " + size + " bytes");
//continue; - If I do not comment this out the size check fails and nothing happens
}

FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(extractFile, bytes);
```

For some reason I am only getting about 1/15 of the data or so into the byte array (43 out of 642 records in one example). I originally thought it was an issue perhaps casting size to int, but size is typically between 1,000,000 - 10,000,000 or so so that isn't a problem. Any thoughts?

Comment: Probably not the issue, but you might want to check that the cast from long to int didn't truncate the value of size. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590831/safely-casting-long-to-int-in-java

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`InputStream.read` is not required to read *all* the data. It will read *some* data, with an amount varying between 1 and the size of the array.

You will have to call the function repeatedly until you read all the data you need.

For reference, check the [API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29): they explicitly say "a smaller number may be read".

Comment: @user1524459 You may wish to try [`IOUtils.toByteArray()`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html#toByteArray%28java.io.InputStream%29) from commons-io as an example of a library method that does this for you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46350/discussion-between-duncan-and-sotirios-delimanolis)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using IOUtils to solve the problem. Thanks for the pointers Flavio, Duncan