# 2 Simple Java questions

Tags: java

First question: I am trying to print out four double values in reverse order so if the user enters "1 2 3 4" I want it to print out "4 3 2 1" Here is my coding.

```
// User enters 4 float values here
System.out.println("Enter 4 float values");
inputValues2 = input.readLine();
String[] dblValues = inputValues2.split("\\s+");
```

Second Question: I want to print out the integer portion of a double value. I guess I am trying to convert the double value to an int. I have tried these two different ways and get errors for both of them. Any ideas?? Maybe I should just do some sort of rounding to a whole number??

```
int dblConvert = dblAverage.intValue();           // One way
int dblConvert = Integer.parseInt(dblAverage);    // Second way
```

Comment: For the first part, what have you done so far? For the second one, simply cast your double to int: `(int) dblAverage`. You can call `dblAverage.intValue()` only on a `Double`, not on a `double` (note the capital D).

Comment: Please restrain to a _single_ question per question and give it a proper title.

Comment: @JensErat I would if I could ask more than 1 question every 90 minutes....

Comment: Think of it as killing 2 birds with 1 stone

Comment: Better use the `nextInt()` method from `Scanner` to iterate over the items (storing the items for reverse order still needed). It will give you single integers even if seperated by multiple whitespaces.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Find the answers/hints for your questions.

1. You have to print the content of the array in reverse order.

   ```
   for (int i = dblValues.length -1;i >= 0; i--) {
       System.out.println(dblValues[i]);
   }
   ```

   This is the fundamental way for a begginer. They are some predifined libraries to do this job
2. You can use [`int a = (int) Math.round(doubleVar);`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round(double))

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for. I will accept answer in 9 min when I am allowed.

Comment: What if I am trying to not print out the variable here and just set the reverse of dblValues[i] for later use...?

Comment: @MarcusBurkhart, Yes, the initial value stored in that array location will be replaced by the newer value. You may try.

Comment: thanks again. Appreciate the help and quick responses.

Answer (score 0):

For your second question: there is a [Math.round()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#round%28double%29()) method. You'll then need to cast the returned long to int in a [safe way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590831/safely-casting-long-to-int-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

If you dont just want to print the numbers in reverse order and order them naturally you can add them to a list and sort them

If you also don't care about rounding you can just cast a double

```
    String s = "4 3 2 1";
    String[] split = s.split("\\s+");
    List<Integer> numbers = new LinkedList<>();

    for (String toAdd : split) {
        numbers.add(Integer.parseInt(toAdd));
    }       

    Collections.sort(numbers);      
    System.out.println(numbers);

    System.out.println((int)45.7654);
```

Answer (score 0):

1.) loop from last index and print in `reverse order`.

2.) Use `Math.round()` for getting int part

```
public static void main(String[] arg) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 4 float values");
        String inputValues2 = input.nextLine();
        String[] dblValues = inputValues2.split("\\s+");

        System.out.println("Reverse order");

        for (int i = dblValues.length - 1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
            System.out.println(dblValues[i]);
        }

        System.out.println("int part ");

        for (String s : dblValues) {
            int a = Math.round(new Float(s));
            System.out.println(a);
        }
    }
```

**output**

```
Enter 4 float values
12.4 23.5 34.5 45.3
Reverse order
45.3
34.5
23.5
12.4
int part 
12
24
35
45
```