# Arrays.copyOfRange( byte[], long, long ) ? in Java

Tags: java, arrays, byte

How can I 'cut' byte array using `Arrays.copyOfRange` with long parameters?

EDIT: I need to cut file ( not larger than 2GB ) from byte index to the end of file ( byte[].length )

```
int size = f.length()
```

throws:
incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from long to int 
(even if the file is 600kB)

```
File f = new File("path-to-file");
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes( f.toPath() );

long indexToCutFrom = a_long_number; 
long indexToCutTo = f.length() - 1;

// method with these parameters does not exists
byte[] cuttedBytes = Arrays.copyOfRange( bytes, indexToCutFrom, indexToCutTo );
```

Comment: How do you have an array with more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` elements?

Comment: Arrays are limited to a length of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` so 2^32 -1. No need of `long` here. So in short, you can't because you don't need to

Comment: @bradimus there's `Unsafe` that can do that

Comment: @Eugene, can you explain more about this? I might have right an answer to quickly ...

Comment: Are you sure `int` would not be enough? What's the reason you want to keep a byte array larger than 2 GB in memory?

Comment: updated my question.

Comment: So, is your question how to cast/convert a `long` to an `int`?

Comment: @bradimus - Yes! Thank you.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590831/safely-casting-long-to-int-in-java

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays` are limited to a length of `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (= 2 ^ 32 -1). No need of `long`.

In short, you can't because you don't need to.

You can see it simply because `Arrays.length()` is an integer.