# Save and Read Integer Firestore Android

Tags: java, android, database, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to create a simple Stats activity for my Android game.  I'm using the new Firestore database.  I have been able to save a document to my Firestore database with a total score, recent score, avg score, total games, and high score, but when i try to read the data back from the database it returns a null.

```
public void readFromDB(){
    statsDoc.get().addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
            if(documentSnapshot.exists()){
                UserData userdata = documentSnapshot.toObject(UserData.class);
            }
        }
```

My Userdata class:

```
/* Copyright statement */

package com.squidstudios.android.balloonpopper.utils;

import com.google.firebase.database.IgnoreExtraProperties;

/**
 * UserData.java
 *
 * This class represents a single user's data including username, email, number of points earned,
 * a saved state of their progress towards earning a single point, and their password.
 */
@IgnoreExtraProperties
public class UserData {
    public String email;
    public int total_points;

public int avg_score;
public int high_score;
public int total_games;
public int prev_score;

public UserData() {
    // Default constructor required for calls to DataSnapshot.getValue(UserData.class)
}


public int getTotal_games() {
    return total_games;
}

public void setTotal_games(int total_games) {
    this.total_games = total_games;
}

public int getTotal_points() {
    return total_points;
}

public void setTotal_points(int total_points) {
    this.total_points = total_points;
}

public int getAvg_score() {
    return avg_score;
}

public void setAvg_score(int avg_score) {
    this.avg_score = avg_score;
}

public int getHigh_score() {
    return high_score;
}

public void setHigh_score(int high_score) {
    this.high_score = high_score;
}


public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public int getPrev_score() {
    return prev_score;
}

public void setPrev_score(int prev_score) {
    this.prev_score = prev_score;
}

}
```

It works fine when I test it out with string but for some reason integers are not working.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

After doing some tests I got to the conclussion we're gonna have to cast Longs to Integers, since that's what we get from fetching a "Number" from firestore.
Here's what my data looks like:
[image: 1]] 
Make sure you stored a "Number" by clicking on the "edit" icon at the end of the field: 
[image]
Use this to do the casting: [Safely casting long to int in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590831/safely-casting-long-to-int-in-java)
My code looks like this:

```
int money = snapshot.getLong("money").intValue();
```

Feel free to ask for further explanation!

Comment: Looks good to me. I would recommend to do the NOT NULL check first for case when field is not provided.

Answer (score 0):

`enter code here`
float TotalAmount = Float.parseFloat
 (String.valueOf(ObjectsrequireNonNull(getSnapshots().getSnapshot(position).getLong("TotalAmount"))));

Try it........ 101 %%%%