# Getting an error while retrieving a number from a Firestore document

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I stored a number in a field of a document and want to retrieve it but I get the following error:
`String resource ID #0x1`

I am using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46735317/save-and-read-integer-firestore-android) method to retrieve the number. Is the number stored in Firestore as Long, Integer or Double? I didn't find any answer to that, and how can I resolve this error so I can retrieve the number and use it in my code?

The error is displayed in the `Toast` line.

Your help is very much appreciated!

Here is my code:

```
    Integer round;

    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private CollectionReference roundRef = db.collection("Games");

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_interim_result);

       ...

        roundRef.document(gameId).collection("Round").document("Round").get()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()){
                            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                            if (document != null){

                                round = document.getLong("round").intValue();

                                Toast.makeText(PlayInterimResultMainActivity.this, round, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
...
```

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot and indicate the line at which that error occurs.

Comment: I found the problem, I was using the integer in my Toast message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem:

The error was in the Toast message, where I didn't transformed the integer into a String value.
Here is the right Toast message:

`Toast.makeText(PlayInterimResultMainActivity.this, round.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`