# Count Elements in a stream and return Integer insted of long

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I need to count Elements in a Stream and assign it to an Integer without casting.

`.count()` does return long

thought about the `.collect(Collectors.reducing(..))` but cant figure it out.
I feel like there is something simple I don't get.

My Try:

```
Stream<String> s = Stream.of("Hallo ", "Test", "String");
Integer count = s.filter(e -> (e.length() >= lb && e.length() <= ub && !e.contains(" ")))
                 .map(e -> e.toUpperCase())
                 .distinct()
                 .collect(Collectors.reducing(0, e -> 1, Integer::sum)));

System.out.println(count);
```

Comment: Show your code dude.

Comment: `count` returns long

Comment: ment long, sorry.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: `int count = (int) ..... .count(); // long to int`

Comment: "without casting" — Why is casting not an option?

Comment: If you can ensure that the number of elements in the stream is within the limits of an Integer, then you can cast/convert it to int.. . You can add a comment to denote this to the readers

Comment: Your `Collectors.reducing` approach looks fine. You only have to remove that one obsolete `)` at the end. Instead of `collect`, you can also use `.reduce(0, (c,e) -> c+1, Integer::sum)`.

Comment: What's your problem? Your code works fine.

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn except that there’s one more `)` than needed.

Comment: Ya, that's a syntax error. But after all I see no casting here. Dont know what OP talking about, and I dont know why they keep posting "answers" below @Holger

Comment: @MạnhQuyếtNguyễn that’s the OP’s solution attempt and indeed, it seems, no one of the answerers noticed that the solution attempt is already sufficient, except for a single dangling brace. Even worse, someone has just edited a solution into the question and that edit even got approved.

Answer (score 8):

Simply: don't.

Don't cast, but also don't make things overly complicated.

Rather look into *safe* ways of getting that int out of the long returned by `count()`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1590831/safely-casting-long-to-int-in-java) for starters:

```
int bar = Math.toIntExact(someLong);
```

for example. When you are 100% sure that the computed value always fits within int, then you just avoid putting down the catch for the potentially thrown ArithmeticException. And you still got that good feeling that you can't "overrun" without noticing.

But as said: don't invest time/energy into specially computing your own stuff, when you can use **built-in** functionality to count things, and turn them into int/Integer. Remember: each character you put into code needs to be *read* and understood later on. Thus even "20 characters" more add up over time. So when you always lean towards the shorter solution, as long as they are easy to read/understand.

Comment: Hey thank you. I would do it as you said. But its an exam task.. so i need to do it. I think the prof want us to use some collect stuff in the stream itself.

Comment: OK, that is a valid requirement, that changes solution space! Then just go and accept on of the answers that does exactly that for you. But remember to tell your instructor that GhostCat told you: "dude, that is not what you should be doing"!

Comment: Im totally with you. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Here is the right way. Convert all the distinct values to `1` using [`Stream::mapToInt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#mapToInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) - it produces the [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) which has [`sum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum--)/[`count`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#count--)  methods able to handle stream of numeric values directly without mapping:

```
Integer count = s.filter(e -> (e.length() >= lb && e.length() <= ub && !e.contains(" ")))
                 .map(String::toUpperCase)
                 .distinct()
                 .mapToInt(i -> 1)
                 .sum();
```

---

Without mapping to `int`, you can use [`Stream::reduce(U identity, BiFunction<U,? super T,U> accumulator, BinaryOperator<U> combiner)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#reduce-U-java.util.function.BiFunction-java.util.function.BinaryOperator-) to get the very same result:

```
Integer count = s.filter(e -> (e.length() >= 2 && e.length() <= 10 && !e.contains(" ")))
                 .map(String::toUpperCase)
                 .distinct()
                 .reduce(0, (a,b) -> a + 1, (a,b) -> a + b);
```

The interface of this method is little bit complicated:

- `U identity` is set to 0 - a start of counting
- `accumulator` (`(a,b) -> a + 1`) converts the String to `int`, each String will be converted to 1 and added to the previous result (0+1+1+1...).
- `combiner` combines two consecutive values (`(a,b) -> a + b`) - the sum of the `1` values, which is practically the count.

Comment: Why do you filter distinct values? OP did not say anything about that :/

Comment: @dbl just scroll the OP’s code example horizontally…

Comment: @dbl: See the code of OP, he uses `distinct()`. I use the very same code.

Comment: @DannyBergs could you edit the question then since what you are asking for and what you are expecting are two different things... :)

Comment: @Nikolas e -> e.toUpperCase() could be replaced with method reference.

Comment: Or `.collect(Collectors.reducing(0, e -> 1, Math::addExact))` which does not map to an `IntStream` but still avoids the boxing overhead *and* will through an exception when the number doesn’t fit into an `int`.

Comment: @Holger nice one :) Still i doubt that the professor will process such a big file just to check students' homework.

Comment: Just to add, instead of collecting and then use the external reduction method presented in Collectors isn't it better just to use s.map(e -> 1).reduce(0, Math::addExact);

Comment: @dbl teachers might be capable of analyzing the quality of a solution without having to try such a behavior, especially when they perhaps had exactly that in mind when saying “don’t cast”. Besides that, you can generate such a long stream using, e.g. `LongStream.range(-100, Integer.MAX_VALUE).mapToObj(Long::toHexString)`, though, in this specific use case, the *current implementation* will never produce too many elements after a `distinct()`. And yes, you can use `.map(e -> 1).reduce(0, Math::addExact);` but that’s just an inefficient variant of `.mapToInt(e -> 1).reduce(0, Math::addExact);`…

Answer (score 3):

If you want to count the elements in stream without using the build in .count() method then you could map each element to an int and reduce by summing them. Something like this:

```
Integer count = s.mapToInt(i -> 1).reduce((a, b) -> a + b).orElse(0);
```

Or as @Holger commented bellow to use the sum() after mapping.

```
Integer count = s.mapToInt(i -> 1).sum();
```

Comment: Well, if you use `.mapToInt(i -> 1)`, you can simply invoke `sum()` on it.

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8, you can use Math.toIntExact(long val).

```
public static int toIntExact(long value)
```

> Returns the value of the long argument; throwing an exception if the
>   value overflows an int.