# Count Java Stream to Integer, not Long

Tags: java, java-stream, collectors

I need to count occurences of some special bundles.

```
Map<Integer,Integer> countBundles(){
    return bundles.stream()
        .bla()
        .bla()
        .bla()
        .collect(groupingBy(Bundle::getId), counting()));
}
```

This code does not compile because counting returns Long.
Is there any beautiful way to return Map<Integer, Integer>?

I have this idea, but it`s ugly

```
  map.entrySet().stream()
     .collect(toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, entry -> (int) entry.getValue().longValue()));
```

Comment: There should be no other way using the `Streams` API. Added to that, I would not agree that what you have tried so far is ugly, as that looks like the obvious way to do it following a functional stype.

Comment: would this link help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51968025/count-elements-in-a-stream-and-return-integer-insted-of-long/51968144

Answer (score 7):

You can use `Collectors.collectingAndThen` to apply a function to the result of your Collector:

```
Map<Integer,Integer> countBundles() {
    return bundles.stream()
        .bla()
        .bla()
        .bla()
        .collect(groupingBy(Bundle::getId, collectingAndThen(counting(), Long::intValue)));
}
```

If you need some other semantics than just a cast, replace `Long::intValue` with some other conversion code.

Comment: To detect int overflow I recommend using `Math::toIntExact`.

Answer (score 4):

There is no build-in way to use `Collectors.counting()` with `Integer`, since generics are invariant. However, you can write a custom `Collector` with minimal effort:

```
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, Integer> countingInt() {
    return Collectors.summingInt(e -> 1);
}
```

You can also use the plain `summingInt(e -> 1)` if you want to use native libraries only.

Example:

```
Map<Integer,Integer> countBundles(){
    return bundles.stream()
        .bla()
        .bla()
        .bla()
   // 1 .collect(groupingBy(Bundle::getId), countingInt()));
   // 2 .collect(groupingBy(Bundle::getId), summingInt(e -> 1)));
}
```

Please note that with signed interpretation, you can count at most `2.147.483.647` elements.